# Mysql Color Scheme

Tags: mysql, colors, terminal, customization

Is there a way to set a color scheme for the mysql client? It might sound trivial, but I'd like to be able to set some level of colors for terminal client.

Comment: What terminal are you using? Or are you using Windows cmd.exe? This isn't really a mysql question.

Comment: I'm using a Mac, regular Terminal. Though I could be using any terminal really. My thought was that maybe there was something like a .vimrc file for the mysql client. So, yeah it is a mysql question ;)

Comment: Did you give any of these options a try? Did any of them work for you?

Comment: It is a MySQL question. I just wondered about this too. I'm tired of the monochrome output of the MySQL client. It would be so much better in colours. Thought I'd check here first, the command line MySQL client doesn't have a color output option it seems.

Comment: fwiw, color is quite the opposite of trivial, especially if (like me) you've got a couple of 4k monitors on your desk and you need to visually process a lot of info that's coming at you all at once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is pretty much awesome tool https://github.com/dbcli/mycli

Besides syntax highlight it offers completion.

[image]

Comment: Perfect tool! I installed it in a sec `$ sudo apt-get install mycli` and the `$ mycli -u root -p root`.

Comment: I've found this tool recently, and I absolutely love it!

Answer (score 58):

I've spent much time trying to solve that question. It took me nearly a year to solve it :)
There is nice option in mysql config called "pager".

I've just published my configs for mysql client and grc (availiable in most nix dists). Check it out on github! https://github.com/nitso/colour-mysql-console

[image]

Comment: awesome! works a treat on osx (just `brew install grc` first). this makes me very happy :)

Comment: I followed the installation manual, but I did not find config files.
"Copy both config files into your home directory"

Comment: @HoussemZitoun config files are: 
[.my.cnf](https://github.com/nitso/colour-mysql-console/blob/master/.my.cnf) and
[.grcat](https://github.com/nitso/colour-mysql-console/blob/master/.grcat)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) if you just want a colour prompt:

```
% rlwrap --prompt-colour='1;34' mysql
```

Note: contrary to convention, rlwrap spells colour with a U.

If you want everything in colour, check out [acoc - Arbitrary Command Output Colourer](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/acoc.shtml). Not sure if it works with interactive programs, you might need to extend it or write your own.

Comment: "color" is just the American way to spell it.

Comment: It seems you have to do: `rlwrap -a -p'RED' mysql` to get it working properly. Without the -a the prompt doesn't get coloured.

Comment: @Neil: Sure, "colour" is how Australians spell it when writing, but most developers use "color" by convention for things like this because it avoids all sorts of unnecessary confusion.

Comment: IMHO you should lead with the acoc answer (which is why I upvoted you).  Additionally, the link to rlwrap seems to be timing out.

Comment: @Jeff thanks for the tip. rlwrap is easier to find on different platforms than acoc. It gets the silver medal though, that’s pretty good right?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have started to use the MySQL client inside an independent vim session with [conque](https://code.google.com/p/conque/).
You get syntax highlighting and some other extra features from Vim, like nowrap, search, horizontal scrolling, etc.

With `:set wrap`:

[image]

With `:set nowrap`:

[image]

If you like Vim I would give it a go:

1. Install conque.
2. Create a new .vimsql (I like a different vimrc for this).
3. Tune it to start conque and mysql by default.
4. Tune it to have some good key mappings for mysql.
5. `alias mysqlcool="vim -u ~/.vimsql"` (or whatever :))

You can have a look at [the vimrc I'm using](https://gist.github.com/DavidEGx/29a59f674174d6d1ff5c).

Answer (score 0):

Mysql text client is really basic, if you need something more advanced, you could try [MySQL Query Browser](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html), which is a GUI client.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the program GRC on MacPorts.

I'm currently working on getting it running to colorize all of my terminal output.  It uses regex to parse everything, so it really comes down to how much regex do you feel like writing.

Answer (score 0):

For colorizing everything you need nothing but a simple `echo`.
Since **mysql** has:

```
system    (\!) Execute a system shell command.
```

you can easily:

[image: mysql_colorize_prompt_1]

But if you want only the `prompt` be in color use [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/)

[image: mysql_colorize_prompt_2]

And if you want to colorize the result of command you can use `grc`
It is a [python](/questions/tagged/python) script that I think read the underline `stdout`, `stderr`  and then colorize it. You can configure it. And since it uses [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) to match the result, in configure file you should write `regex`

[here is some screen-shot](https://github.com/nitso/colour-mysql-console)

---

More detail about ANSI color:

[How to change the output color of echo in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux/28938235#28938235)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ~/.profile [or ~/.bashrc]

```
export MYSQL_PS1="$(echo -e '\033[1;32mmysql \d> \033[0m')"
```

Answer (score -2):

You should set color scheme for your terminal emulator or console window.

Comment: ehh, I already have a color scheme setup for my terminal. I'm looking for stuff specific to Mysql. For example, if every other row was a diff color, or if the prompt was a diff color, or the headers were a diff color. See where I'm driving here?