# How to change the output color of echo in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, echo, terminal-color

I am trying to print a text in the terminal using echo command.

I want to print the text in a red color. How can I do that?

Comment: This link is pretty helpful: http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: echo -e "plain \e[0;31mRED MESSAGE \e[0m reset"

Answer (score 3659):

You can use these [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```
Black        0;30     Dark Gray     1;30
Red          0;31     Light Red     1;31
Green        0;32     Light Green   1;32
Brown/Orange 0;33     Yellow        1;33
Blue         0;34     Light Blue    1;34
Purple       0;35     Light Purple  1;35
Cyan         0;36     Light Cyan    1;36
Light Gray   0;37     White         1;37
```

And then use them like this in your script:

```
#    .---------- constant part!
#    vvvv vvvv-- the code from above
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
printf "I ${RED}love${NC} Stack Overflow\n"
```

which prints `love` in red.

From @james-lim's comment, **if you are using the `echo` command, be sure to use the `-e` flag to allow backslash escapes**.

```
#    .---------- constant part!
#    vvvv vvvv-- the code from above
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
echo -e "I ${RED}love${NC} Stack Overflow"
```

**Note**: Don't add `"\n"` when using `echo` unless you want to add an additional empty line.

Comment: Doesn't work for me -- output: `\e[0;31mHello Stackoverflow\e[0m`

Comment: Did you try it with "-e"? It tells `echo` to enable backslash escapes.

Comment: In MacOSX, using `\x1B` instead of `\e`. `\033` would be ok for all platforms.

Comment: In an ant property file use unicode for the esacpe, e.g. 
red=\u001b[0;31m

Comment: You might note that these do depend on the terminal understanding them. That said, I've never met a terminal that doesn't understand this set. The `0` means "reset"; it isn't strictly required (only if you need a reset), and would be just as valid in the bright versions. (`0;1;30`) (`1` means bright.)

Comment: On my system (bash on ubuntu) I found that for the first number, 1 means bold not bright, and 3 and 4 are italic and underlined, 5 flashes, and 7 changes the background as well. I wonder if there's some sort of specification for these somewhere?

Comment: Like msanford made for tput, here is the "ANSI-Rainbow" `for (( i = 30; i < 38; i++ )); do echo -e "\033[0;"$i"m Normal: (0;$i); \033[1;"$i"m Light: (1;$i)"; done`

Comment: `echo -e` is not portable while `printf` is.  Use `printf`.

Comment: you may need to do `\x33` instead of `\033` (same but octal prefix doesn't work in coffeescript for instance)

Comment: You must use double quotes with `echo` for this to work.

Comment: @everyman you forgot escape ANSI coloring at the end of loop, Sherlock ;)

Comment: Just a heads up for anyone using the popular IDEA series of IDEs, the black/white/gray color codes will look a little jumbled (light gray is darker than dark gray for instance) if you use them in the in-IDE output console, but they do output to an actual terminal correctly

Comment: You can pre-expand the escapes like so `(printf -v R '\e[0;31m'; printf -v Z '\e[0m'; echo "This is a ${R}red$Z word.")`. Then you can use them in a plain echo without `-e` (and even without the double quotes).

Comment: for default color what code do i need to use?

Comment: @everyman you forgot to mention that the first normal value (in that awesome ANSI Rainbow) is black, which makes it invisible in black background consoles.

Comment: with "echo -n" you can direct the echo statement to not add a trailing newline. with this the "\n" can be kept the same.

Comment: Use `\e[` prefix instead of `\033[` to save some typing

Answer (score 1705):

#### some variables that you can use:

```
# Reset
Color_Off='\033[0m'       # Text Reset

# Regular Colors
Black='\033[0;30m'        # Black
Red='\033[0;31m'          # Red
Green='\033[0;32m'        # Green
Yellow='\033[0;33m'       # Yellow
Blue='\033[0;34m'         # Blue
Purple='\033[0;35m'       # Purple
Cyan='\033[0;36m'         # Cyan
White='\033[0;37m'        # White

# Bold
BBlack='\033[1;30m'       # Black
BRed='\033[1;31m'         # Red
BGreen='\033[1;32m'       # Green
BYellow='\033[1;33m'      # Yellow
BBlue='\033[1;34m'        # Blue
BPurple='\033[1;35m'      # Purple
BCyan='\033[1;36m'        # Cyan
BWhite='\033[1;37m'       # White

# Underline
UBlack='\033[4;30m'       # Black
URed='\033[4;31m'         # Red
UGreen='\033[4;32m'       # Green
UYellow='\033[4;33m'      # Yellow
UBlue='\033[4;34m'        # Blue
UPurple='\033[4;35m'      # Purple
UCyan='\033[4;36m'        # Cyan
UWhite='\033[4;37m'       # White

# Background
On_Black='\033[40m'       # Black
On_Red='\033[41m'         # Red
On_Green='\033[42m'       # Green
On_Yellow='\033[43m'      # Yellow
On_Blue='\033[44m'        # Blue
On_Purple='\033[45m'      # Purple
On_Cyan='\033[46m'        # Cyan
On_White='\033[47m'       # White

# High Intensity
IBlack='\033[0;90m'       # Black
IRed='\033[0;91m'         # Red
IGreen='\033[0;92m'       # Green
IYellow='\033[0;93m'      # Yellow
IBlue='\033[0;94m'        # Blue
IPurple='\033[0;95m'      # Purple
ICyan='\033[0;96m'        # Cyan
IWhite='\033[0;97m'       # White

# Bold High Intensity
BIBlack='\033[1;90m'      # Black
BIRed='\033[1;91m'        # Red
BIGreen='\033[1;92m'      # Green
BIYellow='\033[1;93m'     # Yellow
BIBlue='\033[1;94m'       # Blue
BIPurple='\033[1;95m'     # Purple
BICyan='\033[1;96m'       # Cyan
BIWhite='\033[1;97m'      # White

# High Intensity backgrounds
On_IBlack='\033[0;100m'   # Black
On_IRed='\033[0;101m'     # Red
On_IGreen='\033[0;102m'   # Green
On_IYellow='\033[0;103m'  # Yellow
On_IBlue='\033[0;104m'    # Blue
On_IPurple='\033[0;105m'  # Purple
On_ICyan='\033[0;106m'    # Cyan
On_IWhite='\033[0;107m'   # White
```

[image]

#### the escape character in **bash**, **hex** and **octal** respectively:

```
|       | bash  | hex     | octal   | NOTE                         |
|-------+-------+---------+---------+------------------------------|
| start | \e    | \x1b    | \033    |                              |
| start | \E    | \x1B    | -       | x cannot be capital          |
| end   | \e[0m | \x1b[0m | \033[0m |                              |
| end   | \e[m  | \x1b[m  | \033[m  | 0 is appended if you omit it |
|       |       |         |         |                              |
```

#### short example:

```
| color       | bash         | hex            | octal          | NOTE                                  |
|-------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------------|
| start green | \e[32m<text> | \x1b[32m<text> | \033[32m<text> | m is NOT optional                     |
| reset       | <text>\e[0m  | <text>\1xb[0m  | <text>\033[om  | o is optional (do it as best practice |
|             |              |                |                |                                       |
```

#### bash exception:

If you are going to use these codes in your *special bash variables*

- PS0
- PS1
- PS2 (= this is for prompting)
- PS4

you should add extra escape characters so that [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) can interpret them correctly. Without this adding extra escape characters it works but you will face problems when you use `Ctrl + r` for search in your history.

#### exception rule for bash

You should add `\[` before any starting ANSI code and add `\]` after any ending ones.
Example:
in regular usage:  `\033[32mThis is in green\033[0m`
for PS0/1/2/4:     `\[\033[32m\]This is in green\[\033[m\]`

`\[` is for start of a sequence of **non-printable** characters
`\]` is for end of a sequence of **non-printable** characters

Tip: for memorize it you can first add `\[\]` and then put your ANSI code between them:

- `\[start-ANSI-code\]`
- `\[end-ANSI-code\]`

#### type of color sequence:

1. 3/4 bit
2. 8 bit
3. 24 bit

Before diving into these colors, you should know about 4 modes with these codes:

#### 1. color-mode

It modifies the style of color NOT text. For example make the color bright or darker.

- `0`  reset
- `1;`  lighter than normal
- `2;` darker than normal

This mode is not supported widely. It is fully support on Gnome-Terminal.

#### 2. text-mode

This mode is for modifying the style of text NOT color.

- `3;` italic
- `4;` underline
- `5;` blinking (slow)
- `6;` blinking (fast)
- `7;` reverse
- `8;` hide
- `9;` cross-out

and are almost supported.
For example KDE-Konsole supports `5;` but Gnome-Terminal does not and Gnome supports `8;` but KDE does not.

#### 3. foreground mode

This mode is for colorizing the foreground.

#### 4. background mode

This mode is for colorizing the background.

[image]

The below table shows a summary of **3/4 bit** version of ANSI-color

```
|------------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
| color-mode | octal    | hex     | bash  | description      | example (= in octal)         | NOTE                                 |
|------------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|          0 | \033[0m  | \x1b[0m | \e[0m | reset any affect | echo -e "\033[0m"            | 0m equals to m                       |
|          1 | \033[1m  |         |       | light (= bright) | echo -e "\033[1m####\033[m"  | -                                    |
|          2 | \033[2m  |         |       | dark (= fade)    | echo -e "\033[2m####\033[m"  | -                                    |
|------------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|  text-mode | ~        |         |       | ~                | ~                            | ~                                    |
|------------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|          3 | \033[3m  |         |       | italic           | echo -e "\033[3m####\033[m"  |                                      |
|          4 | \033[4m  |         |       | underline        | echo -e "\033[4m####\033[m"  |                                      |
|          5 | \033[5m  |         |       | blink (slow)     | echo -e "\033[3m####\033[m"  |                                      |
|          6 | \033[6m  |         |       | blink (fast)     | ?                            | not wildly support                   |
|          7 | \003[7m  |         |       | reverse          | echo -e "\033[7m####\033[m"  | it affects the background/foreground |
|          8 | \033[8m  |         |       | hide             | echo -e "\033[8m####\033[m"  | it affects the background/foreground |
|          9 | \033[9m  |         |       | cross            | echo -e "\033[9m####\033[m"  |                                      |
|------------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
| foreground | ~        |         |       | ~                | ~                            | ~                                    |
|------------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|         30 | \033[30m |         |       | black            | echo -e "\033[30m####\033[m" |                                      |
|         31 | \033[31m |         |       | red              | echo -e "\033[31m####\033[m" |                                      |
|         32 | \033[32m |         |       | green            | echo -e "\033[32m####\033[m" |                                      |
|         33 | \033[33m |         |       | yellow           | echo -e "\033[33m####\033[m" |                                      |
|         34 | \033[34m |         |       | blue             | echo -e "\033[34m####\033[m" |                                      |
|         35 | \033[35m |         |       | purple           | echo -e "\033[35m####\033[m" | real name: magenta = reddish-purple  |
|         36 | \033[36m |         |       | cyan             | echo -e "\033[36m####\033[m" |                                      |
|         37 | \033[37m |         |       | white            | echo -e "\033[37m####\033[m" |                                      |
|------------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|         38 | 8/24     |                    This is for special use of 8-bit or 24-bit                                            |
|------------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
| background | ~        |         |       | ~                | ~                            | ~                                    |
|------------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|         40 | \033[40m |         |       | black            | echo -e "\033[40m####\033[m" |                                      |
|         41 | \033[41m |         |       | red              | echo -e "\033[41m####\033[m" |                                      |
|         42 | \033[42m |         |       | green            | echo -e "\033[42m####\033[m" |                                      |
|         43 | \033[43m |         |       | yellow           | echo -e "\033[43m####\033[m" |                                      |
|         44 | \033[44m |         |       | blue             | echo -e "\033[44m####\033[m" |                                      |
|         45 | \033[45m |         |       | purple           | echo -e "\033[45m####\033[m" | real name: magenta = reddish-purple  |
|         46 | \033[46m |         |       | cyan             | echo -e "\033[46m####\033[m" |                                      |
|         47 | \033[47m |         |       | white            | echo -e "\033[47m####\033[m" |                                      |
|------------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|         48 | 8/24     |                    This is for special use of 8-bit or 24-bit                                            |                                                                                       |
|------------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
```

[image]

The below table shows a summary of **8 bit** version of ANSI-color

```
|------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------|
| foreground | octal     | hex       | bash    | description      | example                            | NOTE                    |
|------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------|
|        0-7 | \033[38;5 | \x1b[38;5 | \e[38;5 | standard. normal | echo -e '\033[38;5;1m####\033[m'   |                         |
|       8-15 |           |           |         | standard. light  | echo -e '\033[38;5;9m####\033[m'   |                         |
|     16-231 |           |           |         | more resolution  | echo -e '\033[38;5;45m####\033[m'  | has no specific pattern |
|    232-255 |           |           |         |                  | echo -e '\033[38;5;242m####\033[m' | from black to white     |
|------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------|
| foreground | octal     | hex       | bash    | description      | example                            | NOTE                    |
|------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------|
|        0-7 |           |           |         | standard. normal | echo -e '\033[48;5;1m####\033[m'   |                         |
|       8-15 |           |           |         | standard. light  | echo -e '\033[48;5;9m####\033[m'   |                         |
|     16-231 |           |           |         | more resolution  | echo -e '\033[48;5;45m####\033[m'  |                         |
|    232-255 |           |           |         |                  | echo -e '\033[48;5;242m####\033[m' | from black to white     |
|------------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------|
```

The 8-bit fast test:
`for code in {0..255}; do echo -e "\e[38;05;${code}m $code: Test"; done`

[image]

The below table shows a summary of **24 bit** version of ANSI-color

```
|------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+------------------------------------------+-----------------|
| foreground | octal     | hex       | bash    | description | example                                  | NOTE            |
|------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+------------------------------------------+-----------------|
|      0-255 | \033[38;2 | \x1b[38;2 | \e[38;2 | R = red     | echo -e '\033[38;2;255;0;02m####\033[m'  | R=255, G=0, B=0 |
|      0-255 | \033[38;2 | \x1b[38;2 | \e[38;2 | G = green   | echo -e '\033[38;2;;0;255;02m####\033[m' | R=0, G=255, B=0 |
|      0-255 | \033[38;2 | \x1b[38;2 | \e[38;2 | B = blue    | echo -e '\033[38;2;0;0;2552m####\033[m'  | R=0, G=0, B=255 |
|------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+------------------------------------------+-----------------|
| background | octal     | hex       | bash    | description | example                                  | NOTE            |
|------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+------------------------------------------+-----------------|
|      0-255 | \033[48;2 | \x1b[48;2 | \e[48;2 | R = red     | echo -e '\033[48;2;255;0;02m####\033[m'  | R=255, G=0, B=0 |
|      0-255 | \033[48;2 | \x1b[48;2 | \e[48;2 | G = green   | echo -e '\033[48;2;;0;255;02m####\033[m' | R=0, G=255, B=0 |
|      0-255 | \033[48;2 | \x1b[48;2 | \e[48;2 | B = blue    | echo -e '\033[48;2;0;0;2552m####\033[m'  | R=0, G=0, B=255 |
|------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+------------------------------------------+-----------------|
```

[image]

### some screen-shots

foreground 8-bit summary in a `.gif`

[image: foreground.gif]

background 8-bit summary in a `.gif`

[image: background.gif]

#### color summary with their values

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### `blinking` on KDE-Terminal

[image: KDE-blinking]

[image] a simple `C` code that shows you more

[image: cecho_screenshot]

[image] a more advanced tool that I developed to deal with these colors:

[image: bline]

---

#### color-mode shot

[image: fade-normal-bright]

#### text mode shot

[image: only-text-mode]

#### combining is OK

[image: combine]

#### [more shots](https://github.com/k-five/bline/tree/master/screenshot)

### Tips and Tricks for Advanced Users and Programmers:

#### Can we use these codes in a programming language?

Yes, you can. I experienced in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [c](/questions/tagged/c), [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [d](/questions/tagged/d) [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [python](/questions/tagged/python)

#### Do they slow down the speed of a program?

I think, NO.

#### Can we use these on Windows?

3/4-bit Yes, if you compile the code with `gcc`
[some screen-shots on Win-7](https://github.com/k-five/renrem)

#### How to calculate the length of code?

`\033[` = 2, other parts 1

#### Where can we use these codes?

Anywhere that has a `tty` interpreter
`xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, `kde-terminal`, `mysql-client-CLI` and so on.
For example if you want to colorize your output with mysql you can use `Perl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
print "\033[1m\033[31m$1\033[36m$2\033[32m$3\033[33m$4\033[m" while /([|+-]+)|([0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z_]+)|([^\w])/g;
```

store this code in a file name: `pcc` (= Perl Colorize Character) and then put the file a in valid `PATH` then use it anywhere you like.

`ls | pcc`
`df | pcc`

inside `mysql` first register it for `pager` and then try:

```
[user2:db2] pager pcc
PAGER set to 'pcc'
[user2:db2] select * from table-name;
```

[image: pcc]

It does **NOT** handle Unicode.

#### Do these codes only do colorizing?

No, they can do a lot of interesting things. Try:

```
echo -e '\033[2K'  # clear the screen and do not move the position
```

or:

```
echo -e '\033[2J\033[u' # clear the screen and reset the position
```

There are a lot of beginners that want to clear the screen with `system( "clear" )` so you can use this instead of `system(3)` call

#### Are they available in Unicode?

Yes. `\u001b`

#### Which version of these colors is preferable?

It is easy to use `3/4-bit`, but it is much accurate and beautiful to use `24-bit`.
If you do not have experience with [html](/questions/tagged/html) so here is a quick tutorial:
24 bits means:  `00000000` and `00000000` and `00000000`. Each 8-bit is for a specific color.
`1..8` is for [image] and `9..16` for [image] and `17..24` for [image]
So in [html](/questions/tagged/html) `#FF0000` means [image] and here it is: `255;0;0`
in [html](/questions/tagged/html) `#00FF00` means [image] which here is: `0;255;0`
Does that make sense? what color you want combine it with these three 8-bit values.

reference:
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)
[ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)
[tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html)
[tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html)
[misc.flogisoft.com](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)
some blogs/web-pages that I do not remember

Comment: @NeilGuyLindberg **no octal literals** this error is part of Node.js not eslist itself. you can use `x1B[` for eliminate it.

Comment: @ShakibaMoshiri It's not clear from answer how to combine colors until you carefully read [ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php). Just for note:
`echo -e "\033[97;44;1m text \033[m"` will output bold (;1) white color text (;97) on the blue background (;44), and `\033[0m` reset all text attribute (0). Also it depend on a color schema of terminal.

Comment: In this short example column octal, why is it `<text>\033[om` instead of `<text>\033[0m`, letter o instead of number zero?

Comment: @midnite it is a **typo** you can update/edit the answer

Answer (score 1318):

You can use the awesome `tput` command (suggested in [Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5947788/24874)) to produce terminal control codes for all kinds of things.

---

## Usage

Specific `tput` sub-commands are discussed later.

#### Direct

Call `tput` as part of a sequence of commands:

```
tput setaf 1; echo "this is red text"
```

Use `;` instead of `&&` so if `tput` errors the text still shows.

#### Shell variables

Another option is to use shell variables:

```
red=`tput setaf 1`
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0`
echo "${red}red text ${green}green text${reset}"
```

`tput` produces character sequences that are interpreted by the terminal as having a special meaning. They will not be shown themselves. Note that they can still be saved into files or processed as input by programs other than the terminal.

#### Command substitution

It may be more convenient to insert `tput`'s output directly into your `echo` strings using [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```
echo "$(tput setaf 1)Red text $(tput setab 7)and white background$(tput sgr 0)"
```

---

## Example

The above command produces this on Ubuntu:

[image: Screenshot of colour terminal text]

---

## Foreground & background colour commands

```
tput setab [1-7] # Set the background colour using ANSI escape
tput setaf [1-7] # Set the foreground colour using ANSI escape
```

Colours are as follows:

```
Num  Colour    #define         R G B

0    black     COLOR_BLACK     0,0,0
1    red       COLOR_RED       1,0,0
2    green     COLOR_GREEN     0,1,0
3    yellow    COLOR_YELLOW    1,1,0
4    blue      COLOR_BLUE      0,0,1
5    magenta   COLOR_MAGENTA   1,0,1
6    cyan      COLOR_CYAN      0,1,1
7    white     COLOR_WHITE     1,1,1
```

There are also non-ANSI versions of the colour setting functions (`setb` instead of `setab`, and `setf` instead of `setaf`) which use different numbers, not given here.

## Text mode commands

```
tput bold    # Select bold mode
tput dim     # Select dim (half-bright) mode
tput smul    # Enable underline mode
tput rmul    # Disable underline mode
tput rev     # Turn on reverse video mode
tput smso    # Enter standout (bold) mode
tput rmso    # Exit standout mode
```

## Cursor movement commands

```
tput cup Y X # Move cursor to screen postion X,Y (top left is 0,0)
tput cuf N   # Move N characters forward (right)
tput cub N   # Move N characters back (left)
tput cuu N   # Move N lines up
tput ll      # Move to last line, first column (if no cup)
tput sc      # Save the cursor position
tput rc      # Restore the cursor position
tput lines   # Output the number of lines of the terminal
tput cols    # Output the number of columns of the terminal
```

## Clear and insert commands

```
tput ech N   # Erase N characters
tput clear   # Clear screen and move the cursor to 0,0
tput el 1    # Clear to beginning of line
tput el      # Clear to end of line
tput ed      # Clear to end of screen
tput ich N   # Insert N characters (moves rest of line forward!)
tput il N    # Insert N lines
```

## Other commands

```
tput sgr0    # Reset text format to the terminal's default
tput bel     # Play a bell
```

With [compiz wobbly windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/669/wobbly-windows/), the `bel` command makes the terminal wobble for a second to draw the user's attention.

---

## Scripts

`tput` accepts scripts containing one command per line, which are executed in order before `tput` exits.

Avoid temporary files by echoing a multiline string and piping it:

```
echo -e "setf 7\nsetb 1" | tput -S  # set fg white and bg red
```

---

## See also

- See [`man 1 tput`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tput+1)
- See [`man 5 terminfo`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/terminfo/) for the complete list of commands and more details on these options. (The corresponding `tput` command is listed in the `Cap-name` column of the huge table that starts at line 81.)

Comment: Great answer. This is the one that helped me the most. For anyone else who was wondering what I was wondering, the `$()` is a [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). All `tput af 1` does is generate the color code string, but the codes are not printable characters, so typing `tput af 1` alone will produce a blank line of output.

Comment: Note: if you are using CygWin and don't have tput install `ncurses`

Comment: tput also works inside sed for parsing cruft into legible, colorful cruft: https://gist.github.com/nickboldt/fab71da10bd5169ffdfa

Comment: For a full list of the `tput` colours [check out this answer on the Unix StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269085/207392)

Comment: I think `reset=\`tput sgr0\`` should be `reset=\`tput sgr 0\``, with a space.

Comment: This option worked for me using the `fish` shell. Here's an example:

 `tput setaf 5`
 `tput bold`
 `echo "Hello, World"`
 `tput sgr0`

Comment: @monkeypants From [what I can see](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html) `sgr0` is specifically meant for resetting (turning off) the attributes. `sgr 0` can probably fulfill this role too, but `sgr` is a more general command allowing to change attributes.

Comment: Great answer but it's worth emphasizing how vastly superior it is to store tput outputs in shell variables as you show, than to inline tput as you show right after.  Every interpolated call to tput spawns a process and for any serious use of colors for highlighting etc for many lines, calling tput several times for every line creates *serious* visible slowage.  Not to mention inlining tput is much less readable.

Comment: This is much better than hardcoding ANSI escape sequences in your script.

Answer (score 239):

Use `tput` with the `setaf` capability and a parameter of `1`.

```
echo "$(tput setaf 1)Hello, world$(tput sgr0)"
```

Comment: This should be the best option.


what _tput_ does is it will read the terminal info and render the correctly escaped ANSI code for you.


code like `\033[31m` will break the _readline_ library in some of the terminals.

Comment: Explore colours with a simple loop (increase `i`'s upper bound for more shades): `for (( i = 0; i < 17; i++ )); do echo "$(tput setaf $i)This is ($i) $(tput sgr0)"; done`

Comment: Here is a HOWTO on the tput codes: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html

Comment: Agree with @TianChen, code like `\033[31m`will also produce some non relevant characters when the program used to output text is not compatible with such commands. In the other hand, `tput + setaf`commands won't, leaving the output fully readable.
See @BenHarold 's comment, saying : "Doesn't work for me -- output: `\e[0;31mHello Stackoverflow\e[0m`"

Comment: Hm, whats with the difference? Both options produce the same initial color-changing commands, but differ in the trailing command that resets. The direct escape sequences produce exactly the binary output you expect given what was typed in- `\ESC[m`. The `tput` alternative actually produces a slightly different (and longer) sequence of `\ESC(B\ESC[m`. Compare the diff between what is posted here and e.g. `\033[31mHello, world\033[m`. `sgr0` actually produces two trailing escape sequences. Why would this be more preferred over the first option when it came to issues with e.g. readline?

Answer (score 197):

```
echo -e "\033[31m Hello World"
```

The `[31m` controls the text color:

- `30`-`37` sets *foreground* color
- `40`-`47` sets *background* color

A more complete list of color codes [can be found here](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting).

It is good practice to reset the text color back to `\033[0m` at the end of the string.

Comment: echo -e "\033[31m Hello World", the [31m is the color

Comment: thank you for putting in some that I can copy paste

Comment: I like your answer because it is concise :)

Answer (score 112):

I have just amalgamated the good catches in all solutions and ended up with:

```
cecho(){
    RED="\033[0;31m"
    GREEN="\033[0;32m"  # <-- [0 means not bold
    YELLOW="\033[1;33m" # <-- [1 means bold
    CYAN="\033[1;36m"
    # ... Add more colors if you like

    NC="\033[0m" # No Color

    # printf "${(P)1}${2} ${NC}\n" # <-- zsh
    printf "${!1}${2} ${NC}\n" # <-- bash
}
```

And you can just call it as:

```
cecho "RED" "Helloworld"
```

[image]

Comment: Very practical, I just had to replace single quotes with double quotes for GREEN, YELLOW, NC to make it work in my script.

Comment: I had a few problems when showing contents of a file. Replacing `printf` with `echo` helped me solve that.

Comment: in zsh I get: Bad substitution

Comment: @AdrianLopez thanks for noting that! [indirect variable reference](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn) in ZSH uses `${(P)1}` instead of the `${!1}` for bash. I've edited the answer and included both.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know about **indirect variable reference**: `${!1}` as noted above! Otherwise, its all the standard bash function stuff.

Comment: yeah, that's the essence of the answer indeed

Answer (score 57):

My riff on Tobias' answer:

```
# Color
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
YELLOW='\033[0;33m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

function red {
    printf "${RED}$@${NC}\n"
}

function green {
    printf "${GREEN}$@${NC}\n"
}

function yellow {
    printf "${YELLOW}$@${NC}\n"
}
```

[image: $ echo $(red apple) $(yellow banana) $(green kiwi) apple banana kiwi]

Answer (score 43):

This is the **color switch** `\033[`. See [history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Color [**codes**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences) are like `1;32` (Light Green), `0;34` (Blue), `1;34` (Light Blue), etc.

We terminate color sequences with a color switch `\033[` and `0m`, the *no*-color code. Just like opening and closing tabs in a markup language.

```
  SWITCH="\033["
  NORMAL="${SWITCH}0m"
  YELLOW="${SWITCH}1;33m"
  echo "${YELLOW}hello, yellow${NORMAL}"
```

Simple color `echo` function solution:

```
cecho() {
  local code="\033["
  case "$1" in
    black  | bk) color="${code}0;30m";;
    red    |  r) color="${code}1;31m";;
    green  |  g) color="${code}1;32m";;
    yellow |  y) color="${code}1;33m";;
    blue   |  b) color="${code}1;34m";;
    purple |  p) color="${code}1;35m";;
    cyan   |  c) color="${code}1;36m";;
    gray   | gr) color="${code}0;37m";;
    *) local text="$1"
  esac
  [ -z "$text" ] && local text="$color$2${code}0m"
  echo "$text"
}

cecho "Normal"
cecho y "Yellow!"
```

Comment: I'd change the last `text` variable by `text="$color${@: 2}${code}0m"` this way the whole line except the color parameter will be colored.

Comment: @tomazahlin just add -e to echo, as several times mentioned above

Comment: As Wilfred Hughes has suggested, it's better to use `tput` as it's more portable - works in Bash on macOS too. Therefore I actually suggest to use Alireza Mirian's function from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23006365/2693875

Answer (score 37):

Use `tput` to calculate color codes. Avoid using the ANSI escape code (e.g. `\E[31;1m` for red) because it's less portable. Bash on OS X, for example, does not support it.

```
BLACK=`tput setaf 0`
RED=`tput setaf 1`
GREEN=`tput setaf 2`
YELLOW=`tput setaf 3`
BLUE=`tput setaf 4`
MAGENTA=`tput setaf 5`
CYAN=`tput setaf 6`
WHITE=`tput setaf 7`

BOLD=`tput bold`
RESET=`tput sgr0`

echo -e "hello ${RED}some red text${RESET} world"
```

Answer (score 36):

The other answers already give great explanations on how to do this. What I was still missing was a well-arranged overview over the color codes. The wikipedia article ["ANSI escape code"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit) is very helpful at that. However, since colors can often be configured and look differently in each terminal, I prefer to have a function that can be called in the terminal. For this purpose, I have created the following functions to show a color table and remind me of how to set them (with the arrangement being inspired by the wiki article). You could e.g. load them in your .bashrc/.zshrc or put them as a script somewhere.

## 256 colors

[image]

[image]

Generated by this bash/zsh script:

```sh
function showcolors256() {
    local row col blockrow blockcol red green blue
    local showcolor=_showcolor256_${1:-bg}
    local white="\033[1;37m"
    local reset="\033[0m"

    echo -e "Set foreground color: \\\\033[38;5;${white}NNN${reset}m"
    echo -e "Set background color: \\\\033[48;5;${white}NNN${reset}m"
    echo -e "Reset color & style:  \\\\033[0m"
    echo

    echo 16 standard color codes:
    for row in {0..1}; do
        for col in {0..7}; do
            $showcolor $(( row*8 + col )) $row
        done
        echo
    done
    echo

    echo 6·6·6 RGB color codes:
    for blockrow in {0..2}; do
        for red in {0..5}; do
            for blockcol in {0..1}; do
                green=$(( blockrow*2 + blockcol ))
                for blue in {0..5}; do
                    $showcolor $(( red*36 + green*6 + blue + 16 )) $green
                done
                echo -n "  "
            done
            echo
        done
        echo
    done

    echo 24 grayscale color codes:
    for row in {0..1}; do
        for col in {0..11}; do
            $showcolor $(( row*12 + col + 232 )) $row
        done
        echo
    done
    echo
}

function _showcolor256_fg() {
    local code=$( printf %03d $1 )
    echo -ne "\033[38;5;${code}m"
    echo -nE " $code "
    echo -ne "\033[0m"
}

function _showcolor256_bg() {
    if (( $2 % 2 == 0 )); then
        echo -ne "\033[1;37m"
    else
        echo -ne "\033[0;30m"
    fi
    local code=$( printf %03d $1 )
    echo -ne "\033[48;5;${code}m"
    echo -nE " $code "
    echo -ne "\033[0m"
}
```

## 16 colors

[image]

Generated by this bash/zsh script:

```sh
function showcolors16() {
    _showcolor "\033[0;30m" "\033[1;30m" "\033[40m" "\033[100m"
    _showcolor "\033[0;31m" "\033[1;31m" "\033[41m" "\033[101m"
    _showcolor "\033[0;32m" "\033[1;32m" "\033[42m" "\033[102m"
    _showcolor "\033[0;33m" "\033[1;33m" "\033[43m" "\033[103m"
    _showcolor "\033[0;34m" "\033[1;34m" "\033[44m" "\033[104m"
    _showcolor "\033[0;35m" "\033[1;35m" "\033[45m" "\033[105m"
    _showcolor "\033[0;36m" "\033[1;36m" "\033[46m" "\033[106m"
    _showcolor "\033[0;37m" "\033[1;37m" "\033[47m" "\033[107m"
}

function _showcolor() {
    for code in $@; do
        echo -ne "$code"
        echo -nE "   $code"
        echo -ne "   \033[0m  "
    done
    echo
}
```

Comment: would you mind, if I used the functions you posted here in a oh my zsh plugin providing colr and bgcolr functions? It would e.g. `echo -e "$(colr 11 'yellow') normal $(colr 124 'some red')"`. The point of it would be the zsh completion (screenshot).   @coldfix ?

Comment: @Casaper, no problem consider these public domain.

Answer (score 33):

A neat way to change color only for one `echo` is to define such function:

```
function coloredEcho(){
    local exp=$1;
    local color=$2;
    if ! [[ $color =~ '^[0-9]$' ]] ; then
       case $(echo $color | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') in
        black) color=0 ;;
        red) color=1 ;;
        green) color=2 ;;
        yellow) color=3 ;;
        blue) color=4 ;;
        magenta) color=5 ;;
        cyan) color=6 ;;
        white|*) color=7 ;; # white or invalid color
       esac
    fi
    tput setaf $color;
    echo $exp;
    tput sgr0;
}
```

Usage:

```
coloredEcho "This text is green" green
```

Or you could directly use color codes mentioned in [Drew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20983251/1493081):

```
coloredEcho "This text is green" 2
```

Comment: If you add `-n` to echo then you can use it as inline coloring `echo "Red \`coloredEcho "fox" red\` jumps over the lazy dog"`

Answer (score 27):

I found [Shakiba Moshiri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4643584/shakiba-moshiri)'s awesome answer while I was looking info on that topic… then I had an idea… and it ended up in a quite nice function extremely easy to use 
So I've to share it

https://github.com/ppo/bash-colors

**Usage:** `$(c <flags>)` inside an `echo -e` or `printf`

```
 ┌───────┬─────────────────┬──────────┐   ┌───────┬─────────────────┬──────────┐
 │ Code  │ Style           │ Octal    │   │ Code  │ Style           │ Octal    │
 ├───────┼─────────────────┼──────────┤   ├───────┼─────────────────┼──────────┤
 │   -   │ Foreground      │ \033[3.. │   │   B   │ Bold            │ \033[1m  │
 │   _   │ Background      │ \033[4.. │   │   U   │ Underline       │ \033[4m  │
 ├───────┼─────────────────┼──────────┤   │   F   │ Flash/blink     │ \033[5m  │
 │   k   │ Black           │ ......0m │   │   N   │ Negative        │ \033[7m  │
 │   r   │ Red             │ ......1m │   ├───────┼─────────────────┼──────────┤
 │   g   │ Green           │ ......2m │   │   L   │ Normal (unbold) │ \033[22m │
 │   y   │ Yellow          │ ......3m │   │   0   │ Reset           │ \033[0m  │
 │   b   │ Blue            │ ......4m │   └───────┴─────────────────┴──────────┘
 │   m   │ Magenta         │ ......5m │
 │   c   │ Cyan            │ ......6m │
 │   w   │ White           │ ......7m │
 └───────┴─────────────────┴──────────┘
```

**Examples:**

```
echo -e "$(c 0wB)Bold white$(c) and normal"
echo -e "Normal text… $(c r_yB)BOLD red text on yellow background… $(c _w)now on
  white background… $(c 0U) reset and underline… $(c) and back to normal."
```

Answer (score 23):

This question has been answered over and over again :-) but why not.

First using `tput` is more portable in modern environments than manually injecting ASCII codes through `echo -E`

Here's a quick bash function:

```
 say() {
     echo "$@" | sed \
             -e "s/\(\(@\(red\|green\|yellow\|blue\|magenta\|cyan\|white\|reset\|b\|u\)\)\+\)[[]\{2\}\(.*\)[]]\{2\}/\1\4@reset/g" \
             -e "s/@red/$(tput setaf 1)/g" \
             -e "s/@green/$(tput setaf 2)/g" \
             -e "s/@yellow/$(tput setaf 3)/g" \
             -e "s/@blue/$(tput setaf 4)/g" \
             -e "s/@magenta/$(tput setaf 5)/g" \
             -e "s/@cyan/$(tput setaf 6)/g" \
             -e "s/@white/$(tput setaf 7)/g" \
             -e "s/@reset/$(tput sgr0)/g" \
             -e "s/@b/$(tput bold)/g" \
             -e "s/@u/$(tput sgr 0 1)/g"
  }
```

Now you can use:

```
 say @b@green[[Success]]
```

to get:

[image: Bold-Green Success]

## Notes on portability of `tput`

First time `tput(1)` source code was uploaded in September 1986

`tput(1)` has been available in X/Open curses semantics in 1990s (1997 standard has the semantics mentioned below).

So, it's (*quite*) ubiquitous.

Comment: This is pretty cool! Didn't know this. Can you say something about the availability of `tput`? Is it available on most servers where one doesn't have admin rights to install it? Do you have a link to where this technique was first 'invented'?

Comment: tput is the standards compliant way to do this, where it's completely independent of you knowing the terminal capabilities. If the terminal does not support a given capability it will downgrade gracefully to whatever it can do without pushing out screwy escape codes.

Comment: I have stopped using this method as it messes with the cursor position in bash lines. It will randomly wrap before the end of the line, and won't go back all the way to the beginning of the line when using home or the arrow keys. Going back to the clumsy manual escape codes fixes this problem.

Comment: @Resandro - is that because you're using it in `$PS1` without `\[...\]` around the non-spacing parts?  Continue to use the Bash PS1 markers with the tput strings.

Comment: Note that this function does not fully work on MacOsX because of differencies in the sed utility: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/differences-between-sed-on-mac-osx-and-other-standard-sed

Comment: @Jeff I was kinda hoping that OP would learn from the approach rather than blindly cutting and pasting it.  The only reason I brought up `tput` as a portable approach is because it really *is* the correct way to query the terminal

Comment: We can set the cursor position, line and column, using a similar ansi escape sequence.

Comment: This function is spawning an awful lot of subshells (one for every color) on every call

Answer (score 21):

We can use **24 Bits RGB true colors** for both text and background!

```
 ESC[38;2;⟨r⟩;⟨g⟩;⟨b⟩m  /*Foreground color*/
 ESC[48;2;⟨r⟩;⟨g⟩;⟨b⟩m  /*Background color*/
```

Example red text and closing tag:

```
 echo -e "\e[38;2;255;0;0mHello world\e[0m"
```

**Generator:**

```js
text.addEventListener("input",update)
back.addEventListener("input",update)

function update(){
  let a = text.value.substr(1).match(/.{1,2}/g)
  let b = back.value.substr(1).match(/.{1,2}/g)
  out1.textContent = "echo -e \"\\" + `033[38;2;${parseInt(a[0],16)};${parseInt(a[1],16)};${parseInt(a[2],16)}mHello\"`
  out2.textContent = "echo -e \"\\" + `033[48;2;${parseInt(b[0],16)};${parseInt(b[1],16)};${parseInt(b[2],16)}mWorld!\"`
}
```

```css
div {padding:1rem;font-size:larger}
```

```html
TEXT COLOR: <input type="color" id="text" value="#23233">
<br><div id="out1"></div>
BACK COLOR: <input type="color" id="back" value="#FFFF00">
<br><div id="out2">
```

> **24-bit:** As "true color" graphic cards with 16 to 24 bits of color
>   became common, Xterm,KDE's Konsole, as well as all libvte
>   based terminals (including GNOME  Terminal) support 24-bit
>   foreground and background color setting
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#24-bit

***Is it safe to use in my scripts?***

**Yes!** 8 and 16 bits terminals will just display as fallback a color on the range of the available palette, keeping the best contrast, no breakages!

---

Also, nobody noticed the usefulness of the ANSI code 7 **reversed video**.

It stay readable on any terminal schemes colors, black or white backgrounds, or other fancies palettes, by swapping foreground and background colors.

Example, for a red background that works everywhere:

```
echo -e "\033[31;7mHello world\e[0m";
```

This is how it looks when changing the terminal built-in schemes:

[image]

This is the loop script used for the gif.

```
for i in {30..49};do echo -e "\033[$i;7mReversed color code $i\e[0m Hello world!";done
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters

Comment: to fit zsh `for i in {30..49};do echo -e "\033[$i;7mReversed color code $i\e[0m Hello world\!";done`

Answer (score 21):

If you are using `zsh` or `bash`

```sh
black() {
    echo -e "\e[30m${1}\e[0m"
}

red() {
    echo -e "\e[31m${1}\e[0m"
}

green() {
    echo -e "\e[32m${1}\e[0m"
}

yellow() {
    echo -e "\e[33m${1}\e[0m"
}

blue() {
    echo -e "\e[34m${1}\e[0m"
}

magenta() {
    echo -e "\e[35m${1}\e[0m"
}

cyan() {
    echo -e "\e[36m${1}\e[0m"
}

gray() {
    echo -e "\e[90m${1}\e[0m"
}

black 'BLACK'
red 'RED'
green 'GREEN'
yellow 'YELLOW'
blue 'BLUE'
magenta 'MAGENTA'
cyan 'CYAN'
gray 'GRAY'
```

[**Try online**](https://code.labstack.com/olWbeOBr)

Answer (score 21):

## Emoji

one thing you can do that is not mentioned in the answer is to use emojis to color your output!

```
echo : error message
echo : warning message
echo : ok status message
echo : action message
echo : Or anything you like and want to recognize immediately by color
echo : Or with a specific emoji
```

## Bonus Added Value

This method is very useful especially when your source editor for the script supports displaying Unicode. Then you can also see the colorful script even before running it and **directly in the source**! :

[image: VSCode demo]
<sub>Image of a script file inside the VSCode</sub>

**Note**: You may need to pass the Unicode of the emoji directly:

```
echo $'\U0001f972'  // this emoji:
```

<sub>Note the **capital `U`** for Unicode characters >= 10000</sub>

---

**Also**, It's very rare but you may need to pass the code like this:

```
echo <0001f972>
```

Thanks to @joanis from comments for mentioning this

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but the color of the emojis don't get rendered in my terminal, they're all converted to the current color being output.

Comment: Also, `echo <0001f972>` doesn't work for me. In what context does that syntax work? For Unicode characters <=ffff, `echo $'\u1234'` works, but not for >=10000.

Comment: Just found the answer for >=10000: `echo $'\U0001f972'` with a capital U. (figured it out from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280481/327696 by guessing bash and vim might mimic each other)

Answer (score 20):

Thanks to **@k-five** for this answer

```
declare -A colors
#curl www.bunlongheng.com/code/colors.png

# Reset
colors[Color_Off]='\033[0m'       # Text Reset

# Regular Colors
colors[Black]='\033[0;30m'        # Black
colors[Red]='\033[0;31m'          # Red
colors[Green]='\033[0;32m'        # Green
colors[Yellow]='\033[0;33m'       # Yellow
colors[Blue]='\033[0;34m'         # Blue
colors[Purple]='\033[0;35m'       # Purple
colors[Cyan]='\033[0;36m'         # Cyan
colors[White]='\033[0;37m'        # White

# Bold
colors[BBlack]='\033[1;30m'       # Black
colors[BRed]='\033[1;31m'         # Red
colors[BGreen]='\033[1;32m'       # Green
colors[BYellow]='\033[1;33m'      # Yellow
colors[BBlue]='\033[1;34m'        # Blue
colors[BPurple]='\033[1;35m'      # Purple
colors[BCyan]='\033[1;36m'        # Cyan
colors[BWhite]='\033[1;37m'       # White

# Underline
colors[UBlack]='\033[4;30m'       # Black
colors[URed]='\033[4;31m'         # Red
colors[UGreen]='\033[4;32m'       # Green
colors[UYellow]='\033[4;33m'      # Yellow
colors[UBlue]='\033[4;34m'        # Blue
colors[UPurple]='\033[4;35m'      # Purple
colors[UCyan]='\033[4;36m'        # Cyan
colors[UWhite]='\033[4;37m'       # White

# Background
colors[On_Black]='\033[40m'       # Black
colors[On_Red]='\033[41m'         # Red
colors[On_Green]='\033[42m'       # Green
colors[On_Yellow]='\033[43m'      # Yellow
colors[On_Blue]='\033[44m'        # Blue
colors[On_Purple]='\033[45m'      # Purple
colors[On_Cyan]='\033[46m'        # Cyan
colors[On_White]='\033[47m'       # White

# High Intensity
colors[IBlack]='\033[0;90m'       # Black
colors[IRed]='\033[0;91m'         # Red
colors[IGreen]='\033[0;92m'       # Green
colors[IYellow]='\033[0;93m'      # Yellow
colors[IBlue]='\033[0;94m'        # Blue
colors[IPurple]='\033[0;95m'      # Purple
colors[ICyan]='\033[0;96m'        # Cyan
colors[IWhite]='\033[0;97m'       # White

# Bold High Intensity
colors[BIBlack]='\033[1;90m'      # Black
colors[BIRed]='\033[1;91m'        # Red
colors[BIGreen]='\033[1;92m'      # Green
colors[BIYellow]='\033[1;93m'     # Yellow
colors[BIBlue]='\033[1;94m'       # Blue
colors[BIPurple]='\033[1;95m'     # Purple
colors[BICyan]='\033[1;96m'       # Cyan
colors[BIWhite]='\033[1;97m'      # White

# High Intensity backgrounds
colors[On_IBlack]='\033[0;100m'   # Black
colors[On_IRed]='\033[0;101m'     # Red
colors[On_IGreen]='\033[0;102m'   # Green
colors[On_IYellow]='\033[0;103m'  # Yellow
colors[On_IBlue]='\033[0;104m'    # Blue
colors[On_IPurple]='\033[0;105m'  # Purple
colors[On_ICyan]='\033[0;106m'    # Cyan
colors[On_IWhite]='\033[0;107m'   # White


color=${colors[$input_color]}
white=${colors[White]}
# echo $white



for i in "${!colors[@]}"
do
  echo -e "$i = ${colors[$i]}I love you$white"
done
```

---

## Result

[image]

Hope this [image](http://www.bunlongheng.com/code/colors.png) help you to pick your color for your bash :D

Comment: It should be noted that this requires bash v4.

Answer (score 18):

I instead of hard coding escape codes that are specific to your current terminal, you should use `tput`.

This is my favorite demo script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

tput init

end=$(( $(tput colors)-1 ))
w=8
for c in $(seq 0 $end); do
    eval "$(printf "tput setaf %3s   " "$c")"; echo -n "$_"
    [[ $c -ge $(( w*2 )) ]] && offset=2 || offset=0
    [[ $(((c+offset) % (w-offset))) -eq $(((w-offset)-1)) ]] && echo
done

tput init
```

[image: 256 colors output by tput]

Answer (score 15):

These codes work on my Ubuntu box:

[image]

```
echo -e "\x1B[31m foobar \x1B[0m"
echo -e "\x1B[32m foobar \x1B[0m"
echo -e "\x1B[96m foobar \x1B[0m"
echo -e "\x1B[01;96m foobar \x1B[0m"
echo -e "\x1B[01;95m foobar \x1B[0m"
echo -e "\x1B[01;94m foobar \x1B[0m"
echo -e "\x1B[01;93m foobar \x1B[0m"
echo -e "\x1B[01;91m foobar \x1B[0m"
echo -e "\x1B[01;90m foobar \x1B[0m"
echo -e "\x1B[01;89m foobar \x1B[0m"
echo -e "\x1B[01;36m foobar \x1B[0m"
```

This prints the letters a b c d all in different colors:

```
echo -e "\x1B[0;93m a \x1B[0m b \x1B[0;92m c \x1B[0;93m d \x1B[0;94m"
```

For loop:

```
for (( i = 0; i < 17; i++ )); 
do echo "$(tput setaf $i)This is ($i) $(tput sgr0)"; 
done
```

[image]

Comment: By the way: This does not depend much on having installed a specific version of ubuntu, but using PuTTY!

Answer (score 12):

## For readability

If you want to improve the **readability** of the code, you can `echo` the string first then add the color later by using `sed`:

```
echo 'Hello World!' | sed $'s/World/\e[1m&\e[0m/'
```

Comment: I really like this answer! Can you please explain the $ in the sed command though?

Comment: The $'<something>' is for bash, not sed.  It tell bash to process the \e as an escape sequence, and put an "escape" character in.  Usually you see the simpler forms like $'\t' or $'\n' to get a tab or newline character passed to a command.

Answer (score 12):

Heres what I ended up with using `sed`

```
echo " [timestamp] production.FATAL Some Message\n" \
"[timestamp] production.ERROR Some Message\n" \
"[timestamp] production.WARNING Some Message\n" \
"[timestamp] production.INFO Some Message\n" \
"[timestamp] production.DEBUG Some Message\n"  | sed \
-e "s/FATAL/"$'\e[31m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/ERROR/"$'\e[31m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/WARNING/"$'\e[33m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/INFO/"$'\e[32m'"&"$'\e[m'"/" \
-e "s/DEBUG/"$'\e[34m'"&"$'\e[m'"/"
```

Prints like this:
[image: Mac sed output to colour]

Answer (score 10):

My favourite answer so far is coloredEcho.

Just to post another option, you can check out this little tool xcol

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/01/23/colorize-your-stdout-with-xcol/

you use it just like grep, and it will colorize its stdin with a different color for each argument, for instance

```
sudo netstat -putan | xcol httpd sshd dnsmasq pulseaudio conky tor Telegram firefox "[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+" ":[[:digit:]]+" "tcp." "udp." LISTEN ESTABLISHED TIME_WAIT
```

[image: xcol example]

Note that it accepts any regular expression that sed will accept.

This tool uses the following definitions

```
#normal=$(tput sgr0)                      # normal text
normal=$'\e[0m'                           # (works better sometimes)
bold=$(tput bold)                         # make colors bold/bright
red="$bold$(tput setaf 1)"                # bright red text
green=$(tput setaf 2)                     # dim green text
fawn=$(tput setaf 3); beige="$fawn"       # dark yellow text
yellow="$bold$fawn"                       # bright yellow text
darkblue=$(tput setaf 4)                  # dim blue text
blue="$bold$darkblue"                     # bright blue text
purple=$(tput setaf 5); magenta="$purple" # magenta text
pink="$bold$purple"                       # bright magenta text
darkcyan=$(tput setaf 6)                  # dim cyan text
cyan="$bold$darkcyan"                     # bright cyan text
gray=$(tput setaf 7)                      # dim white text
darkgray="$bold"$(tput setaf 0)           # bold black = dark gray text
white="$bold$gray"                        # bright white text
```

I use these variables in my scripts like so

```
echo "${red}hello ${yellow}this is ${green}coloured${normal}"
```

Answer (score 10):

to show the message output with diffrent color you can make :

```
echo -e "\033[31;1mYour Message\033[0m"
```

> -Black        0;30     Dark Gray     1;30
>
> -Red          0;31     Light Red     1;31
>
> -Green        0;32     Light Green   1;32
>
> -Brown/Orange 0;33     Yellow        1;33
>
> -Blue         0;34     Light Blue    1;34
>
> -Purple       0;35     Light Purple  1;35
>
> -Cyan         0;36     Light Cyan    1;36
>
> -Light Gray   0;37     White         1;37

Answer (score 10):

I'm using [this](https://github.com/vaniacer/bash_color) for color printing

```
#!/bin/bash
#--------------------------------------------------------------------+
#Color picker, usage: printf $BLD$CUR$RED$BBLU'Hello World!'$DEF     |
#-------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
#       Text color        |       Background color         |         |
#-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+         |
# Base color|Lighter shade| Base color   | Lighter shade   |         |
#-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+         |
BLK='\e[30m'; blk='\e[90m'; BBLK='\e[40m'; bblk='\e[100m' #| Black   |
RED='\e[31m'; red='\e[91m'; BRED='\e[41m'; bred='\e[101m' #| Red     |
GRN='\e[32m'; grn='\e[92m'; BGRN='\e[42m'; bgrn='\e[102m' #| Green   |
YLW='\e[33m'; ylw='\e[93m'; BYLW='\e[43m'; bylw='\e[103m' #| Yellow  |
BLU='\e[34m'; blu='\e[94m'; BBLU='\e[44m'; bblu='\e[104m' #| Blue    |
MGN='\e[35m'; mgn='\e[95m'; BMGN='\e[45m'; bmgn='\e[105m' #| Magenta |
CYN='\e[36m'; cyn='\e[96m'; BCYN='\e[46m'; bcyn='\e[106m' #| Cyan    |
WHT='\e[37m'; wht='\e[97m'; BWHT='\e[47m'; bwht='\e[107m' #| White   |
#-------------------------{ Effects }----------------------+---------+
DEF='\e[0m'   #Default color and effects                             |
BLD='\e[1m'   #Bold\brighter                                         |
DIM='\e[2m'   #Dim\darker                                            |
CUR='\e[3m'   #Italic font                                           |
UND='\e[4m'   #Underline                                             |
INV='\e[7m'   #Inverted                                              |
COF='\e[?25l' #Cursor Off                                            |
CON='\e[?25h' #Cursor On                                             |
#------------------------{ Functions }-------------------------------+
# Text positioning, usage: XY 10 10 'Hello World!'                   |
XY () { printf "\e[$2;${1}H$3"; }                                   #|
# Print line, usage: line - 10 | line -= 20 | line 'Hello World!' 20 |
line () { printf -v _L %$2s; printf -- "${_L// /$1}"; }             #|
# Create sequence like {0..(X-1)}                                    |
que () { printf -v _N %$1s; _N=(${_N// / 1}); printf "${!_N[*]}"; } #|
#--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

All basic colors set as vars and also there are some usefull functions: XY, line and que. Source this script in one of yours and use all color vars and functions.

Answer (score 10):

You may "combined" colours and text-mode.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo red text / black background \(Reverse\)
echo "\033[31;7mHello world\e[0m";
echo -e "\033[31;7mHello world\e[0m";
echo

echo yellow text / red background
echo "\033[32;41mHello world\e[0m";
echo -e "\033[32;41mHello world\e[0m";
echo "\033[0;32;41mHello world\e[0m";
echo -e "\033[0;32;41mHello world\e[0m";
echo

echo yellow BOLD text / red background
echo "\033[1;32;41mHello world\e[0m";
echo -e "\033[1;32;41mHello world\e[0m";
echo

echo yellow BOLD text underline / red background
echo "\033[1;4;32;41mHello world\e[0m";
echo -e "\033[1;4;32;41mHello world\e[0m";
echo "\033[1;32;4;41mHello world\e[0m";
echo -e "\033[1;32;4;41mHello world\e[0m";
echo "\033[4;32;41;1mHello world\e[0m";
echo -e "\033[4;32;41;1mHello world\e[0m";
echo
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To expand on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5947802/1329367), for the lazy of us:

```
function echocolor() { # $1 = string
    COLOR='\033[1;33m'
    NC='\033[0m'
    printf "${COLOR}$1${NC}\n"
}

echo "This won't be colored"
echocolor "This will be colorful"
```

Comment: Don't hardcode terminal escapes.  Use `tput`; that's what it's for!

Comment: @TobySpeight Although that may be true for multi-platform support (in theory), if poster finds it works in their own world, why disagree and dissuade others in similar world from using the technique? Case in point I'm trying similar in Ubuntu 16.04 bash and it works. As the only user on this platform I find this answer acceptable. I will also use `tput` for `sc` and `rc` though (save cursor, restore cursor). Although this answer calls me "lazy" it could be reworded as "practical" or "straight to the point".

Answer (score 6):

You should definitely use tput over raw ANSI control sequences.

> Because there's a large number of different terminal control
>   languages, usually a system has an intermediate communication layer.
>   The real codes are looked up in a database for the currently detected
>   terminal type and you give standardized requests to an API or (from
>   the shell) to a command.
>
> One of these commands is `tput` . `tput` accepts a set of acronyms called
>   capability names and any parameters, if appropriate, then looks up the
>   correct escape sequences for the detected terminal in the terminfo
>   database and prints the correct codes (the terminal hopefully
>   understands).

from http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes

That said, I wrote a small helper library called [bash-tint](https://github.com/ArtBIT/bash-tint), which adds another layer on top of tput, making it even simpler to use (imho):

Example:

`tint "white(Cyan(T)Magenta(I)Yellow(N)Black(T)) is bold(really) easy to use."`

Would give the following result:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

And this what I used to see all combination and decide which reads cool:

```
for (( i = 0; i < 8; i++ )); do
    for (( j = 0; j < 8; j++ )); do
        printf "$(tput setab $i)$(tput setaf $j)(b=$i, f=$j)$(tput sgr0)\n"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I've written [swag](https://github.com/mwheregroup/swag) to achieve just that.

You can just do

```
pip install swag
```

Now you can install all the escape commands as txt files to a given destination via:

```
swag install -d <colorsdir>
```

Or even easier via:

```
swag install
```

Which will install the colors to `~/.colors`.

Either you use them like this:

```
echo $(cat ~/.colors/blue.txt) This will be blue
```

Or this way, which I find actually more interesting:

```
swag print -c red -t underline "I will turn red and be underlined"
```

Check it out on [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/a/dbnmog9yj2u3pvl4iq45arfk2)!

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @nachoparker's answer, I have this in my `.bashrc`:

```sh
#### colours
source xcol.sh

### tput foreground
export tpfn=$'\e[0m' # normal
export tpfb=$(tput bold)

## normal colours
export tpf0=$(tput setaf 0) # black
export tpf1=$(tput setaf 1) # red
export tpf2=$(tput setaf 2) # green
export tpf3=$(tput setaf 3) # yellow
export tpf4=$(tput setaf 4) # blue
export tpf5=$(tput setaf 5) # magenta
export tpf6=$(tput setaf 6) # cyan
export tpf7=$(tput setaf 7) # white
# echo "${tpf0}black ${tpf1}red ${tpf2}green ${tpf3}yellow ${tpf4}blue ${tpf5}magenta ${tpf6}cyan ${tpf7}white${tpfn}"

## bold colours
export tpf0b="$tpfb$tpf0" # bold black
export tpf1b="$tpfb$tpf1" # bold red
export tpf2b="$tpfb$tpf2" # bold green
export tpf3b="$tpfb$tpf3" # bold yellow
export tpf4b="$tpfb$tpf4" # bold blue
export tpf5b="$tpfb$tpf5" # bold magenta
export tpf6b="$tpfb$tpf6" # bold cyan
export tpf7b="$tpfb$tpf7" # bold white
# echo "${tpf0b}black ${tpf1b}red ${tpf2b}green ${tpf3b}yellow ${tpf4b}blue ${tpf5b}magenta ${tpf6b}cyan ${tpf7b}white${tpfn}"
```

The `export` allows me to use those `tpf..` in Bash scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Here there is a simple script to easily manage the text style in bash shell promt:

https://github.com/ferromauro/bash-palette

Import the code using:

```
source bash-palette.sh
```

Use the imported variable in echo command (use the -e option!):

```
echo -e ${PALETTE_GREEN}Color Green${PALETTE_RESET}
```

It is possible to combine more elements:

```
echo -e ${PALETTE_GREEN}${PALETTE_BLINK}${PALETTE_RED_U}Green Blinking Text over Red Background${PALETTE_RESET}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Here is the simplest and readable solution. 
With bashj (https://sourceforge.net/projects/bashj/), you would simply choose one of these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

W="Hello world!"
echo $W

R=130
G=60
B=190

echo u.colored($R,$G,$B,$W)

echo u.colored(255,127,0,$W)
echo u.red($W)
echo u.bold($W)
echo u.italic($W)

Y=u.yellow($W)
echo $Y
echo u.bold($Y)
```

`256x256x256` colors are available if you have the color support in your terminal application.

Answer (score -5):

```
red='\e[0;31m'
NC='\e[0m' # No Color
echo -e "${red}Hello Stackoverflow${NC}"
```

This answer correct, except that the call to colors should not be inside the quotes.

```
echo -e ${red}"Hello Stackoverflow"${NC}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Works fine inside the quotes. the -e switch evaluate what's in quotes too. Running both (inside and outside quotes) using bash -x outputs the same executed command `echo -e '\e[0;31mHello Stackoverflow\e[0m'`. So it's just the same for bash.