# Bash colour one word using echo

Tags: bash, colors, echo

I am wanting to colourize one word in the middle of an echo sentence, but can't seem to achieve this.

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash
wipe="\033[1m\033[0m"
yellow='\E[1;33'
echo -e "$yellow"
echo Hello World
echo -e "$wipe"
```

But this doesn't:

```
#!/bin/bash
wipe="\033[1m\033[0m"
yellow='\E[1;33'
black="40m"
echo -e "Output a $yellow coloured $wipe word."
# or
echo -e "Output a ${yellow} coloured ${wipe} word."
```

What am I stupidly doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot an `m` in your ANSI escape code for `yellow`. This works:

```
yellow='\E[1;33m'
```

Answer (score 20):

Much better, use [tput](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html) to set a foreground colour:

```
textreset=$(tput sgr0) # reset the foreground colour
red=$(tput setaf 1)
yellow=$(tput setaf 2) 

echo "Output a ${yellow} coloured ${textreset} ${red} word ${textreset}."
```

Comment: I shall have a dabble with tput, only seen it recently, looks good. Thanks.

Comment: There are [other colours and commands](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20983251/24874) for `tput` too. It's an awesome little tool for shell scripting.

Comment: how does this compare, performance-wise, with explicitly putting in the escape code?