# Setup bash script for aws ubuntu server node.js installation fails

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, amazon-web-services, mean-stack

I'm trying to write a node.js/MEAN.JS setup bash script based on a script to create a custom node.js development environment on a AWS Ubuntu server.

Well so far so good, but when I tried to start and generalize the script (adding MEAN installation to it) the tests start to fail. It looks like it doesn't install any of the node programs:

```
    Testing Basic dependencies:
    git                           OK
    gcc                           OK
    g++                           OK
    autoconf                      OK
    automake                      OK
    libtool                       OK
    python                        OK
    make                          OK

    Testing Basic command line editor installations:
    rlwrap                        OK
    emacs                         OK
    nano                          OK

    Testing Node.JS installations:
    node                          missing
    nvm                           missing
    npm                           missing
    heroku                        OK
    foreman                       OK

    Testing MEAN JS Stack installations:
    mongo                         OK
    mongod                        OK
    mean                          missing
    bower                         missing
    grunt                         missing
```

Also when I try to execute for example `node`, I get the following error:

```
    $ node
    The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
     * node
     * nodejs
    Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

The weird thing is when the bash script is executed it seems to be installing everything fine. I've been looking around and can't find why this is happening and what the solution should be? Can it have anything to do with the `$PATH`?

setup.sh source code:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #Added this usefull function from a Stack Overflow post:
    #Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux
    function coloredEcho(){
        local exp=$1;
        local color=$2;
        if ! [[ $color =~ '^[0-9]$' ]] ; then
           case $(echo $color | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') in
            black) color=0 ;;
            red) color=1 ;;
            green) color=2 ;;
            yellow) color=3 ;;
            blue) color=4 ;;
            magenta) color=5 ;;
            cyan) color=6 ;;
            white|*) color=7 ;; # white or invalid color
           esac
        fi
        tput setaf $color;
        echo $exp;
        tput sgr0;
    }

    #Base installation function:
    #Is from:
    #Link: https://github.com/startup-class/setup/blob/master/setup.sh

    function baseInstall() {
        # Simple setup.sh for ISMAT School Project
        cd
        apt-get install -y curl

        coloredEcho "Installing project structure:" blue

        # Installing dependencies:
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install -y git
        sudo apt-get install -y gcc g++ autoconf automake libtool
        sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python make
        sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev

        # Install jshint to allow checking of JS code within emacs
        # http://jshint.com/
        npm install -g jshint

        # Install rlwrap to provide libreadline features with node
        # See: http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl
        sudo apt-get install -y rlwrap

        # Install emacs24
        # https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs
        sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:cassou/emacs
        sudo apt-get -qq update
        sudo apt-get install -y emacs24-nox emacs24-el emacs24-common-non-dfsg

        # Install nvm: node-version manager
        # https://github.com/creationix/nvm
        curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh

        # Load nvm and install latest production node
        source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
        source ~/.profile
        nvm ls-remote
        nvm install v0.10.26
        nvm use v0.10.26

        # git pull and install dotfiles as well
        cd $HOME
        if [ -d ./dotfiles/ ]; then
            mv dotfiles dotfiles.old
        fi
        if [ -d .emacs.d/ ]; then
                mv .emacs.d .emacs.d~
        fi
        git clone https://github.com/cmpsoares91/dotfiles.git
        ln -sb dotfiles/.screenrc .
        ln -sb dotfiles/.bash_profile .
        ln -sb dotfiles/.bashrc .
        ln -sb dotfiles/.bashrc_custom .
        ln -sf dotfiles/.emacs.d .

        sudo apt-get update
    }

    install=1

    if [ $1 == server ] ; then
        coloredEcho "Starting Server Instalation..." red

        # Instaling Base:
        baseInstall

        # Install Heroku toolbelt
        # https://toolbelt.heroku.com/debian
        wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh

        # All extra stuff for server add here

        coloredEcho "Server Setup Ready" red

    elif [ $1 == dev ] ; then
        coloedEcho "Starting Developer Instalation..." green

        # Instaling Base:
        baseInstall

        coloredEcho "Developer Setup Ready" green

    else
        coloredEcho "No selection made." blue
        install=0
    fi

    if [ $install == 1 ] ; then 
        coloredEcho "Install MEAN JavaScript Stack as well? (y/n)" magenta
        a=1
        while [ $a == 1 ]
        do
            a=0
            read meanOption
            if [ $meanOption == y ] ; then
                coloredEcho "Starting MEAN JavaScript Stack Instalation..." red

                #Add MEAN.io installation commands...

                #Installing MongoDB:
                sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
                echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
                sudo apt-get update
                sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

                #Installing Bower:
                npm install bower

                #Installing MEAN.io:
                sudo npm install -g meanio@latest

                #Start App Right away?
                coloredEcho "--> Want to initiate mean App now? (y/n)" red
                c=1
                while [ $c == 1 ]
                do
                    c=0
                read appOption
                    if [ $appOption == y ] ; then
                        coloredEcho "----> Enter App name:" red
                        read myApp
                            mean init $myApp
                            cd $myApp && npm install
                            grunt
                    elif [ $appOption == n ] ; then
                        #Nothing Happens...
                        coloredEcho "--> Not initiation App..." red
                    else
                        coloredEcho "--> Please enter y or n:" red
                        c=1
                    fi
                done
            elif [ $meanOption == n ] ; then
                #Nothing Happens...
                coloredEcho "Not installing MEAN..." red
            else
                coloredEcho "Please enter y or n:" magenta
                a=1
            fi
        done

        g=1
        while [ $g == 1 ]
        do
            g=0
            coloredEcho "Do you want to install Grunt.JS? (y/n)" green
            read gruntOption
            if [ $gruntOption == y ] ; then
            # Install Grunt for automated node builds
            # http://gruntjs.com/getting-started for details
            npm install -g grunt-cli
        elif [ $gruntOption == n ] ; then
                #Nothing Happens...
                    coloredEcho "--> Not Installing Grunt.js..." green
            else
                    coloredEcho "--> Please enter y or n:" green
                    g=1
            fi
        done
    fi
```

test.sh source code:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #Bash Script for installation testing
    #Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script

    echo "Testing Basic dependencies:"
    for cmd in "git" "gcc" "g++" "autoconf" "automake" "libtool" "python" "make" ; do
      printf "%-30s" "$cmd"
      if hash "$cmd" 2>/dev/null; then printf "OK\n"; else printf "missing\n"; fi
    done

    echo -e "\nTesting Basic command line editor installations:"
    for cmd in "rlwrap" "emacs" "nano"; do
      printf "%-30s" "$cmd"
      if hash "$cmd" 2>/dev/null; then printf "OK\n"; else printf "missing\n"; fi
    done

    echo -e "\nTesting Node.JS installations:"
    for cmd in "node" "nvm" "npm" "heroku" "foreman"; do
      printf "%-30s" "$cmd"
      if hash "$cmd" 2>/dev/null; then printf "OK\n"; else printf "missing\n"; fi
    done

    echo -e "\nTesting MEAN JS Stack installations:"
    for cmd in "mongo" "mongod" "mean" "bower" "grunt"; do
      printf "%-30s" "$cmd"
      if hash "$cmd" 2>/dev/null; then printf "OK\n"; else printf "missing\n"; fi
    done
```

Complete source code is all available here: https://github.com/cmpsoares91/Node.js-Project-Setup

I posted the links because the code is quite big. Also, I made it all opensource so if you want to contribute to it, it's fine by me.

P.S. Admins and moderators: Don't kill me if I do something wrong in the Question post, it's my first, please notify me and I'll edit immediately.

---

Edit 1:

The nvm show that's it's installed:

```
    [ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-0A-28-86:~]$nvm

    Node Version Manager

    Usage:

    (...)
```

But when executing test it still shows as missing. `node npm mean bower and grunt` continue to stay missing and unexecutable.

Edit 2: Added Source code after Louis's comment, Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you post your question to SO it should *also* benefit future readers. Since links are fragile (they become invalid or the information they point to becomes irrelevant to the question here), the code that is causing your problem must be included in the body of your question. If you cannot cut-and-paste the part of your code that pertains to your question, this is a sure sign that your question is not a good fit for SO. Please see this [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, I will re-edit it then. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was causing the problem, in one or two cases it had to do with the fact I forgot add `sudo`, but not most of it.

The problem was that nvm doesn't actually fully install node.js, npm etc. So I had to do those installations via the `apt-get install node` like this:

```
# Installing last node and npm version
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

And the other installations should be done after this with the `sudo npm install [package] command.

The code ends up looking like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #Added this usefull function from a Stack Overflow post:
    #Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux
    function coloredEcho(){
       (...)
    }

    #Base installation function:
    #Is from:
    #Link: https://github.com/startup-class/setup/blob/master/setup.sh

    function baseInstall() {
        # Simple setup.sh for ISMAT School Project
        cd
        sudo apt-get install -y curl

        coloredEcho "Installing project structure:" blue

        # Installing dependencies:
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install -y git
        sudo apt-get install -y gcc g++ autoconf automake libtool
        sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python make
        sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev
        sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common

        # Install emacs24
        # https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs
        sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:cassou/emacs
        sudo apt-get -qq update
        sudo apt-get install -y emacs24-nox emacs24-el emacs24-common-non-dfsg

        # Install rlwrap to provide libreadline features with node
        # See: http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl
        sudo apt-get install -y rlwrap

        # Installing last node and npm version
        sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
        # Still Testing if this is necessary:
        # ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

        # Install nvm: node-version manager
        # Link: https://www.npmjs.org/package/nvm
        sudo npm install -g nvm
        sudo export PATH=./node_modules/.bin:$PATH

        # Install jshint to allow checking of JS code within emacs
        # http://jshint.com/
        sudo npm install -g jshint

        # git pull and install dotfiles as well
        cd $HOME
        if [ -d ./dotfiles/ ]; then
            mv dotfiles dotfiles.old
        fi
        if [ -d .emacs.d/ ]; then
                mv .emacs.d .emacs.d~
        fi
        git clone https://github.com/cmpsoares91/dotfiles.git
        ln -sb dotfiles/.screenrc .
        ln -sb dotfiles/.bash_profile .
        ln -sb dotfiles/.bashrc .
        ln -sb dotfiles/.bashrc_custom .
        ln -sf dotfiles/.emacs.d .

        sudo apt-get update
    }

    install=1

    if [ $1 == server ] ; then
        coloredEcho "Starting Server Instalation..." red

        # Instaling Base:
        baseInstall

        # Install Heroku toolbelt
        # https://toolbelt.heroku.com/debian
        wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh

        # All extra stuff for server add here

        coloredEcho "Server Setup Ready" red

    elif [ $1 == dev ] ; then
        coloedEcho "Starting Developer Instalation..." green

        # Instaling Base:
        baseInstall

        coloredEcho "Developer Setup Ready" green

    else
        coloredEcho "No selection made." blue
        install=0
    fi

    if [ $install == 1 ] ; then 
        coloredEcho "Install MEAN JavaScript Stack as well? (y/n)" magenta
        a=1
        while [ $a == 1 ]
        do
            a=0
            read meanOption
            if [ $meanOption == y ] ; then
                coloredEcho "Starting MEAN JavaScript Stack Instalation..." red

                #Installing MongoDB:
                sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
                echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
                sudo apt-get update
                sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

                #Installing Bower:
                sudo npm install -g bower

                #Installing MEAN.io:
                sudo npm install -g meanio@latest

                #Start App Right away?
                coloredEcho "--> Want to initiate mean App now? (y/n)" red
                c=1
                while [ $c == 1 ]
                do
                    c=0
                read appOption
                    if [ $appOption == y ] ; then
                        coloredEcho "----> Enter App name:" red
                        read myApp
                        mean init $myApp
                        cd $myApp && npm install
                    elif [ $appOption == n ] ; then
                        #Nothing Happens...
                        coloredEcho "--> Not initiation App..." red
                    else
                        coloredEcho "--> Please enter y or n:" red
                        c=1
                    fi
                done
            elif [ $meanOption == n ] ; then
                #Nothing Happens...
                coloredEcho "Not installing MEAN..." red
            else
                coloredEcho "Please enter y or n:" magenta
                a=1
            fi
        done

        g=1
        while [ $g == 1 ]
        do
            g=0
            coloredEcho "Do you want to install Grunt.JS? (y/n)" green
            read gruntOption
            if [ $gruntOption == y ] ; then
            # Install Grunt for automated node builds
            # http://gruntjs.com/getting-started for details
            sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
        elif [ $gruntOption == n ] ; then
                #Nothing Happens...
                    coloredEcho "--> Not Installing Grunt.js..." green
            else
                    coloredEcho "--> Please enter y or n:" green
                    g=1
            fi
        done
    fi
```

And now the test is complete and all the programs run as expected.
Test Output:

```
    $ bash ./test.sh
    Testing Basic dependencies:
    git                           OK
    gcc                           OK
    g++                           OK
    autoconf                      OK
    automake                      OK
    libtool                       OK
    python                        OK
    make                          OK

    Testing Basic command line editor installations:
    rlwrap                        OK
    emacs                         OK
    nano                          OK

    Testing Node.JS installations:
    node                          OK
    nvm                           OK
    npm                           OK
    heroku                        OK
    foreman                       OK

    Testing MEAN JS Stack installations:
    mongo                         OK
    mongod                        OK
    mean                          OK
    bower                         OK
    grunt                         OK
```

Comment: Hi. I found your answer really useful, however do you know why when I try to run the setup.sh I get this returned - 'sudo: apt-get: command not found, sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found, line 78: git: command not found'. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need to indicate the installation at hand. In the repo's readme the I wrote that you can use `./setup.sh dev|server` the dev option excludes the heroku installations. I didn't add more options because I didn't need more but you can fork and edit it to your needs.

Comment: Makes sense - but when I do 'bash ./setup.sh dev' I still get the same errors. Do I need to add apt-get and all the others ones? If so any idea how? Btw... +1 for such a fast response for such an old question! :)

Comment: Open an issue in the repo with all the outputs and I'll see what I can do. It's probably a OS compatibility issue or something like it. ;-)