# Unix Bash Shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

could anyone help me out with the relevant output of the following code snippet

```
echo -e "33[31m Hello World]"
```

I wish to print `hello world` in red in this case.

Comment: Where does PHP come into this question?

Comment: Isn't this bash's `echo`, not PHP's? http://www.linfo.org/echo.html Maybe this thread would be useful for you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -e "\033[31m Hello World\e[0m"
```

Though you should

- rename your question
- use google