# Access terminal emulator's colors in a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal-emulator

In a Bash script I need to print out some text in colors.

However, I don't want to specify fixed colors. I want to use the ones that are specified by the terminal(/-emulator).

How can I programmatically access them? Usually these must be a set of 16 colors. Two of them must be labeled background and foreground.

There should be a way to do so, since other programs as fish, Emacs, etc. also appear in the colors specified in the terminal emulator.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux

Comment: You are probably thinking of `tput`. Here's a good [documentation](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php) you can start with.

Comment: thx! this is already a great help. I could capture the numbered colors via tput (from 0-15) now, but what about the two others: "foreground" and "background", they are also specified in the theme of my terminal emulator.

Comment: `setaf` and `setab` are used to set the foreground and background colors.

Comment: oh, I used (tput setaf n) for setting the foreground color. But I'm looking for the specified color for background and foreground.

Comment: for instance: I'd like to generate a color like so: read out the background-color, then change this color a bit towards grey.  If the background is a dark color like black, the color will be slightly brighter. If the background color is a light color like white, the color will be slightly darker...

Comment: All colors are terminal-specific. ANSI may say, for example, that `\e[32m` instructs the terminal to use green, but it's ultimately up to the terminal emulator to decide what "green" means. You can only find out the "real" color being used if the specific terminal emulator provides a way to make that query.

Comment: Unfortunately `tput` is not written to read the current color of the terminal, hence the name `tput`. It can only query for the capability. You'll probably get lucky with a more advanced ncurse based programming. Try writing in c or c++ with ncurse.

Answer (score 0):

Make a color profile file `profile` like below

```
export RED='\033[0;31m'
export GREEN='\033[1;32m'
export WHITE='\033[1;37m'
```

Include the above file in your script and change the color using `printf` as needed.

```
#!/bin/bash
source $( dirname $0 )/profile

#Switching to RED

printf "${RED}"
ls

#Switching to GREEN

printf "${GREEN}"
echo "Current working directory is "`pwd`
echo "/etc/passwd contents"
cat /etc/passwd

#Switching back to white

printf "${WHITE}"

echo "Some white stuff"
```

The colors persist till we change them.