# How to color every echo line in shell script?

Tags: shell, colors, echo

What I want to do is coloring every echo output line in an .sh script.

Like:

```
echo 'Download stuff...'
wget http://fdsfdsf.com/fgf.png
cd /home
echo 'Got it'
```

--->

```
[IN_COLOR]Download stuff...[IN_COLOR]
http://fdsfdsf.com/fgf.png
[IN_COLOR]Got it[IN_COLOR]
```

...can't paint in Stack Overflow ^^

Comment: The thing is I want write it just once in the script. Not every time if i echo.

Comment: Did you look at all the answers, including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23006365/3266847)?

Comment: Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28709668/3266847)?

Comment: Thats great! THX alot Benjamin :]