# How to stop the effect of ANSI text color code or set text color back to default after certain characters?

Tags: bash, terminal, ansi-colors

What is the scope of ANSI color codes. In following code everything is coming in blue. I only want "Compiled Successfully" in blue. Is there something like closing tags (eg.  in HTML) here?

```
cout<<"\n\e[0;34mCompiled Successfully!!\n";
sym_table.render();
cout<<"\n\nAll variables according to sizes:\n";
for(auto el: addr_table){
    cout<<el.first<<"     "<<el.second<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to add `reset` at the end of your string

```
# Reset
Color_Off='\033[0m'       # Text Reset

# Regular Colors
Black='\033[0;30m'        # Black
Red='\033[0;31m'          # Red
Green='\033[0;32m'        # Green
Yellow='\033[0;33m'       # Yellow
Blue='\033[0;34m'         # Blue
Purple='\033[0;35m'       # Purple
Cyan='\033[0;36m'         # Cyan
White='\033[0;37m'        # White
```

the:

```
cout<<"\n\e[0;34mCompiled Successfully!!\n";
```

should be:

```
cout  << "\n\e[0;34mCompiled Successfully!!\e[m\n";
```

or better:

```
\033[0;34mCompiled Successfully!!\033[m
```

For more details:

### [How to change the output color of echo in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux/28938235#28938235)

---

NOTE that in C++:
You can:

```
#define blue "\033[0;34"
#define reset "\033[m"
...
...
...
std::cout << blue << "your-string" << reset << '\n';
```