# How to get bash to output color when run in a script?

Tags: bash, colors

I pulled an example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux) question to create the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash
export GREEN='\033[0;32m'
export RED='\033[0;31m'
export NC='\033[0m' # No Color
echo "I ${RED}love${NC} ${GREEN}Stack Overflow${NC}"
```

It works as expected if I source the file. However, running it as an executable results in the control codes being printed to the screen instead of the colors changing. I presume I need to send some flag to bash to enable the colors, but what?

Comment: taken from your linked question : `if you are using the echo command, be sure to use the -e flag to allow backslash escapes.`

Comment: .. or just use the `printf` to be compliant `printf "I ${RED}love${NC} ${GREEN}Stack Overflow${NC}"`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need export here, and it's simpler to make sure the correct escape character is added to each variable, rather than making `echo` or `printf` do the replacement.

```
GREEN=$'\e[0;32m'
RED=$'\e[0;31m'
NC=$'\e[0m'

echo "I ${RED}love${NC} ${GREEN}Stack Overflow${NC}"
```

Better yet, use `tput` to get the correct sequence for your terminal instead of assuming ANSI escape sequences.

```
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
NC=$(tput sgr0)
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the colours from `tput setaf`

```
1 -> red
2 -> green
3 -> yellow
4 -> blue
5 -> pink
6 -> cyan
7 -> white
```