# ANSI Colors in Intellij Terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

#### Context:

- I am trying to set up [Powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) on **WSL**
- On my **Windows Machine**
- Which I have set up to be the terminal in **Intellij** which is running on **windows**

The colors were displayed in a very odd way. I came across the question [How to change the output color of echo in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux) which suggested the use of the following command to test the color outputs.

> `for code in {0..255}; do echo -e "\033[48;5;${code}m $code      "; done | paste - - - - - - - -`

Which gave the following result.
[image: Output]

<s>I had similar results when trying to make use of the WSL bash terminal.</s>
**Edit:** This only happens when in intellij. bash.exe and the ubuntu terminal do not have this issue.

## What is the correct way to make use of 8-bit and/or 24-bit color in intellij/WSL?

Comment: From my experimenting, it seems that the terminal thinks it is using 8-bit color, but Intellij is taking it's output and converting it back to the main ANSI colors which can be adjusted in the settings.

Comment: Am I got you right that running WSL on  windows show proper colors, but when you set it as a terminal in IDE colors are wrong?

Comment: Yes. When I set the terminal to "bash.exe" instead of "cmd.exe", the bash window shows up with limited colors as shown above, but if I open bash.exe outside of Intellij, it will have the full range of 8-bit color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Intellij Idea version 2021.3, the terminal now supports 24-bit color thanks to ConPTY support on Windows.