# Can i grep ( or filter) lines of a particular color from the terminal output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

i read this question [How to change the output color of echo in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux)

it seems that its a special character which makes color to appear

can i grep using this?

My use case is . i have unit test output which is very big but most of the lines are success for a test and some are red which are failures, i want to filter out the lines which indicate success.

*I am on a macbook currently if that matters*

Comment: What do you mean? A certain character or string is shown in a certain colour. If you want to `grep` on that particular colour, you can simply try to find out which character or string causes that colour to appear.

Comment: You cannot necessarily just `grep` for the color codes. It depends upon the program outputting the text. Some of them turn off color codes if the output is redirected.

Comment: @lurker - good point - could try adding `--color always` to the command. Many commands support this option if they do the auto redirection detection.

Comment: If your unit test output is identifying success *only* by color, it's broken. There should be some *actual* text you can filter on.

Comment: Another option is whether the command supports structured output such as xml, which will be easier to parse

Comment: @chepener then gcc is broken! And I agree that it is. It prints "warning" for warnings, but nothing distinctive for errors Grepping for "escape red" is as good as you can get.

Comment: Any comment on Nahuel answer?

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible using PCRE, for example depending on actual code used to color

```
grep -P '\e\[31m' <<< $'\e[31mred\e[0m  \n \e[34mblue\e[0m'
grep -P '\e\[34m' <<< $'\e[31mred\e[0m  \n \e[34mblue\e[0m'
```

may be also

```
grep -P '\e\[1;31m' <<< $'\e[1;31mred\e[0m  \n \e[34mblue\e[0m'
```