# Print files and directories using if-then-else and state whether or not it's a file or directory

Tags: if-statement, testing, conditional-statements

Create an if-then-else statement to test if a file, represented by the variable $filename, is in fact a file. The statement should also output a notification message which indicates the result of the test.

My goal is to incorporate the above, but by listing the contents of the current directory only and next to each line it states if it's a file or directory [maybe in color].

So far I have gotten this to work.

```
filename="wp-config.php"

if   [ -f "${filename}" ]
    then echo "${filename} is a file"
elif [ -d "${filename}" ] ;
    then echo "${filename} is a directory"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop throgh all files using for:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in ./*; do
    if [ -f "${filename}" ] ; 
        then echo "${filename} is a file" 
    elif [ -d "${filename}" ] ; 
        then echo "${filename} is a directory" 
    fi
done
```

You could change colour using ANSI code as mentioned here: [Change output color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux)