# How to printf $@

Tags: bash

I have a function in bash that accepts unknown amount of arguments:

```
printAndRunCommand() {
  printf "$@"
  eval "$@"
}
```

Because printf accept only single argument, when I run this command with

```
printAndRunCommand wget stackoverflow.com
```

only `wget` gets printed. I can archive the same effect using `echo` command, but I use printf specific characters like color change, in origin command looks like `printf '"\033[4;36m$@\e[0;33;40m"`.

How do I pass `"$@"` to `printf` command?

Comment: those `\033[4;36m` are ANSI escape code and is no way related to printf. Just embed the escape character directly, or use `\033`/`\e` and use `echo -e` to make it escape special characters. [How to change the output color of echo in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5947742/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$*` to turn the list of arguments into a single string.

```
printf '%s\n' "$*"
```

Better yet, use `%q` to quote metacharacters.

```
printf '%q ' "${@}"; printf '\n'
```

```
$ printAndRunCommand 'a b' c 'foo$bar'
a\ b c foo\$bar
```

If you've got bash 4.4+ you can use `@Q` for nicer looking output that's still properly quoted.

```
printf '%s\n' "${*@Q}"
```

```
$ printAndRunCommand 'a b' c 'foo$bar'
'a b' 'c' 'foo$bar'
```

Comment: Thanks for the `@Q` reference, I haven't come across that before. I don't understand why the bash providers used `q` to mean `escaped` (despite them telling is it means "quoted", it clearly doesn't) and now are using a completely different approach outside of `printf` to really get `quoted` (we couldn't just have something like `%E` for escaped and `%Q` for quoted?) but I suppose we should all just be thankful something exists!