# Git bash - Different colours depending on Repo

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I'm using Windows. 
I use the Open Command Line plugin for Visual Studio that let's met open a git bash at project level by just pressing ALT+SPACE.

Now, given that I work on multiple solutions, therefore multiple repos at the same time, I was wondering if there is a way to change the background or the foreground colour of git bash screen depending on the Repo.

Like for example if repo name is repo1 then background is white, if it's repo2 then background is black.

I'm not sure where to start from regarding this, I tried to change colour in git bash by directly right-clicking the screen, but then it changes it for all the instances (not for only one repo).

Anyone ever tried/did this ?

Comment: answer is YES. start with `echo -e '\033[38;2;255;0;0mRed Text\033[m' ` . Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux