# Is there any way to change text color in C?

Tags: c

I use GCC on Ubuntu 18.04.
I want  the text to be a different color. 
For example:

```c
printf("hello world");
```

I tried using conio.h but the compiler gives me an error that conio.h is not available. how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<conio.h>` is typical for Windows. In Linux, you put some control codes in your string.
Most of sources describe how to do that in bash (like this one [How to change the output color of echo in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux)), but you can easlly use it in C. So first you can use hexdump to get how sequence in bash translate to string:

```
$ echo -e "\033[0;31m" foo #this print foo in red
foo

$ echo -e "\033[0;31m" foo | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 30 3b 33 31 6d 20  66 6f 6f 0a              |.[0;31m foo.|
0000000c
```

As you can see, just first part has to be changed to binary code 0x1b.

Finaly I write code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    printf("%c[0;31mFOO\n", 0x1b);
    return 0;
}
```

And it prints *FOO* in red. Actually it doesn't change color back, but I don't care because I have a color prompt. :)

Answer (score 0):

Terminals are usually (even on Windows) controlled by [Ansi Escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). You can use them to control the output color, or the location of the cursor. See: [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences