# How to color the output of unix script with color based on status

Tags: linux, shell, unix

We a unix script with gives status of monitoring activity. Eg.

```
sh monitoring_activity.sh
```

O/p -

```
RUNNING| TASK1
RUNNING| TASK2
SUCCESS| TASK3
FAILED | TASK4
```

Since the number of records are huge ~200, we need to color the output of the script as

- Record with RUNNING Status in YELLOW
- Record with SUCCESS Status in GREEN
- Record with FAILED Status in RED

Is there any way to achieve the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4842424/1030675

Comment: (1) One possibility is to adapt the code of your script to emit the escape sequences for colouring. But be careful!!! If you run your script in a terminal which does not support ANSI colour codes (rare nowadays, but not impossible), or redirect the output to another program, where the colouring is a nuisance, your script should emit the lines without colour information. (2) If you don't want to do this, another strategy is to write a wrapper (say: `colorize`), which analyzes the output and inserts the colour codes where necessary.

Comment: Why is this tagged _linux_ **and** _unix_?

Comment: this link has a example to colorize in bash script: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092331/how-to-colorize-command-output-in-bash-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092331/how-to-colorize-command-output-in-bash-script)