# How do I access a variable in awk if the variable name is in a string?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a variable in bash `RED_FONT='tput setaf 1'` and I have a string inside an awk command `str="RED_FONT"`. I want to access RED_FONT variable inside awk.
Currently I am passing the bash variable into awk by `awk -v RED_FONT=$(echo $RED_FONT)`

Comment: Looks good apart from the lack of quotes best I can tell. Did you have a problem you'd like help with?

Comment: Currently I have RED_FONT='\033[0;31m' inside awk. What I want is to use the variable str="RED_FONT" to access '\033[0;31m'

Comment: I have the shell variable inside the awk script. What I can't undertand is how to access the variable given the variable name in a string

Comment: Suppose I have the variable abc=4 inside by awk command. I want to access 4 using 'abc', just like I could do it in bash using ${!abc}

Comment: See [GNU Awk User Guide - 6.1 Constants, Variables, and Conversions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Values.html#Values)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can just say `str=RED_FONT "foo"`in awk to make `str` hold your escape sequence plus the three characters `foo`.  You don't use `$` on regular variables in awk, and putting two strings right next to each other joins them together.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you're trying to do as the words you're using to describe your needs are changing between the question and your comments and could really mean any of several different things.

Comment: `awk -v RED_FONT=$(echo $RED_FONT)` just `awk -v RED_FONT="$RED_FONT"`. And remember about quotes.

Comment: Awk doesn't have access to shell variables that weren't either `export`ed or passed to it on the command line. If this is just a regular variable, awk has no way to read it.

Comment: (By the way, all-caps names are reserved for variables that modify behavior of the shell or operating system; names you come up with yourself should have at least one lowercase character, per https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)

Comment: @EdMorton Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57448342/sed-inside-awk-with-system-is-not-working/57448776

Comment: @RwitabanGoswami You could have just edited this question ^^^

Answer (score 3):

If you `export` your shell variable to the environment, then `awk` can look it up by name.

Thus:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -a ## automatically export variables upon definition
fg_RED=$(tput setaf 1)
fg_WHITE=$(tput setaf white)
set +a ## turn off auto-export

awk '{ print(ENVIRON[$1]); print $2; print(ENVIRON[$3]) }' <<EOF
fg_RED print_me_in_red fg_WHITE
EOF
```

A shell variable that is neither `export`ed nor passed on awk's command line (as with `awk -v varname="$value"`) is simply not accessible to awk at all.