# is it possible to make the terminal input line on mac os stand out more (add color, etc.)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

its hard to see where the input line is if it prints out a lot of text. I know you can change the "theme" of the terminal but it doesnt affect the input line

Comment: Do you mean the prompt? The part after which you type your command? Something like `user@machine ~/path/to/dir $` or similar?

Comment: You can find more about colors on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux . To use it as your input line, `open -e ~/.bash_profile` and at the end on a new line, add this line. Lets say you want a red colors, `PS1="\033[0;31m\h:\W \u\$\033[0m "`.  Search more about PS1 env var, color codes and `.bash_profile`. Remember every interactive shell on macos is defaulted to be a login shell, so don't use `.bashrc` (I am not sure what's the process if you updated to zsh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to switch terminal emulators then I know that [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) has this as a feature. It can be activated in iTerm2 by going to View>Show Cursor Guide or by hitting <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>. I however do not think that it is possible to acomplish this another way. You can see the effects of the line highlight in a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1336511/iterm-window-highlighted-on-the-current-line).