# Is there a way to set the console font/background colour on Linux?

Tags: linux, delphi, console, delphi-10.3-rio

Under Windows it is possible to set the console font attributes with `SetConsoleTextAttribute`. This requires the Windows API. Is there a Linux equivalent?

Comment: How this question is related with Delphi?

Comment: @Dima because you can create linux console applications using Delphi

Comment: Use ‘writeln’ in combination with the info @DelphiCoder is refering to

Comment: @jww - This is not a general Linux question, it is specifically related to setting the font attributes from a Delphi application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5947742/11329562