# Is colorama the only way to change the python shell output colour?

Tags: python

So I have been trying to change the colour of the output in the shell, but it just ends up returning boxes. I am using python 3.7.4.

[image: The code and the output]

Comment: Not all terminals support coloured output. Apparently, IDLE is one of those. Try running this in the command line.

Comment: About the boxes see the comment above, about other ways see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Printing colored output depends on what platform you are on. The most common way to do this is by printing [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). But that is not supported on all terminals, thus why you see those boxes / weird characters

You can use [cmder](https://cmder.net/) which works on windows and supports ANSI

[image]