# Difference in the output of Spyder and Repl.it vs. Visual Studio and Command Line - [34mR vs letter R (with blue collor)

Tags: python, chess

I am using a command-line chess game that I am taking from [here](https://github.com/marcusbuffett/command-line-chess).
If I run the main.py part of the code using the "repl.it" or anaconda I will get what I expect:
[image]

But if I try to run via anaconda command line or visual studio I get this:
[image]

Comment: @JoanLaraGanau you are right. My problem is if I try to copy and paste my problem in words it does not work. For example, the little question mark round with a square, if I copy and paste it disappears.

Comment: `[34m` looks like a [shell colour code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux) - I think it will work in Unix shells (Linux or Mac OS), but not the windows command prompt. There are ways to install `bash` on Windows, and if you run it in `bash` it should work.

Comment: @JoanLaraGanau. This is actually a semi-decent use-case for images, since we are talking about colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython, like many terminal emulators on Unix-Like systems, has built in support for [ANSI Color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors). The escape characters you see in the Windows terminal are automatically converted to color commands by IPython.

You can get similar support for your python programs on Windows using the [`colorama`](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) library. For the output you are attempting, do

```
import colorama
colorama.init()
```

This will replace `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` with file objects that strip away escape sequences and perform corresponding Windows CMD operations.

If you want this to happen outside of Python as well, consider installing `ansi.sys` on your machine, as the `colorama` documentation suggests.