# Strange behaviour of bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell

I have 2 scripts.
`script.conf`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail
# set -o xtrace

[ -f $HOME/Templates/bash_colors.sh ] && source $HOME/Templates/bash_colors.sh

INFO=${INFO:-"1"}
DEBUG=${DEBUG:-"0"}
ERROR=${ERROR:-"1"}

Red=${Red:-}
Yellow=${Yellow:-}
Cyan=${Cyan:-}
Color_Off=${Color_Off:-}
__msg_error() {
    [[ "${ERROR}" == "1" ]] && echo -e "${Red}[ERROR]: $*${Color_Off}";
}

__msg_debug() {
    [[ "${DEBUG}" == "1" ]] && echo -e "${Yellow}[DEBUG]: $*${Color_Off}";
}

__msg_info() {
    [[ "${INFO}" == "1" ]] && echo -e "${Cyan}[INFO]: $*${Color_Off}";
}
```

and `testConf.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# INFO="0"

scriptDir="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"
[ -f ${scriptDir}/script.conf ] && source ${scriptDir}/script.conf

INFO="0"


__msg_error "Test error1"

__msg_info "Test Info"

__msg_error "Test error2"

__msg_debug "Test debug"
```

The strange thing is if set `INFO` to 0 I would expect that both error messages would be echoed which is not the case. Just the first will printed. I don't understand why. Maybe you have an idea?

It seem like the script is stopped when `INFO` is 0.

See the trace:

```
++ INFO=1
++ DEBUG=0
++ ERROR=1
++ Red='\033[0;31m'
++ Yellow='\033[0;33m'
++ Cyan='\033[0;36m'
++ Color_Off='\033[0m'
+ INFO=0
+ __msg_error 'Test error1'
+ [[ 1 == \1 ]]
+ echo -e '\033[0;31m[ERROR]: Test error1\033[0m'
[ERROR]: Test error1
+ __msg_info 'Test Info'
+ [[ 0 == \1 ]]
```

But why?

`bash_colors.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash


# src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28938235/1959528
# Reset
Color_Off='\033[0m'       # Text Reset

# Regular Colors
Black='\033[0;30m'        # Black
Red='\033[0;31m'          # Red
Green='\033[0;32m'        # Green
Yellow='\033[0;33m'       # Yellow
Blue='\033[0;34m'         # Blue
Purple='\033[0;35m'       # Purple
Cyan='\033[0;36m'         # Cyan
White='\033[0;37m'        # White

# Bold
BBlack='\033[1;30m'       # Black
BRed='\033[1;31m'         # Red
BGreen='\033[1;32m'       # Green
BYellow='\033[1;33m'      # Yellow
BBlue='\033[1;34m'        # Blue
BPurple='\033[1;35m'      # Purple
BCyan='\033[1;36m'        # Cyan
BWhite='\033[1;37m'       # White

# Underline
UBlack='\033[4;30m'       # Black
URed='\033[4;31m'         # Red
UGreen='\033[4;32m'       # Green
UYellow='\033[4;33m'      # Yellow
UBlue='\033[4;34m'        # Blue
UPurple='\033[4;35m'      # Purple
UCyan='\033[4;36m'        # Cyan
UWhite='\033[4;37m'       # White

# Background
On_Black='\033[40m'       # Black
On_Red='\033[41m'         # Red
On_Green='\033[42m'       # Green
On_Yellow='\033[43m'      # Yellow
On_Blue='\033[44m'        # Blue
On_Purple='\033[45m'      # Purple
On_Cyan='\033[46m'        # Cyan
On_White='\033[47m'       # White

# High Intensity
IBlack='\033[0;90m'       # Black
IRed='\033[0;91m'         # Red
IGreen='\033[0;92m'       # Green
IYellow='\033[0;93m'      # Yellow
IBlue='\033[0;94m'        # Blue
IPurple='\033[0;95m'      # Purple
ICyan='\033[0;96m'        # Cyan
IWhite='\033[0;97m'       # White

# Bold High Intensity
BIBlack='\033[1;90m'      # Black
BIRed='\033[1;91m'        # Red
BIGreen='\033[1;92m'      # Green
BIYellow='\033[1;93m'     # Yellow
BIBlue='\033[1;94m'       # Blue
BIPurple='\033[1;95m'     # Purple
BICyan='\033[1;96m'       # Cyan
BIWhite='\033[1;97m'      # White

# High Intensity backgrounds
On_IBlack='\033[0;100m'   # Black
On_IRed='\033[0;101m'     # Red
On_IGreen='\033[0;102m'   # Green
On_IYellow='\033[0;103m'  # Yellow
On_IBlue='\033[0;104m'    # Blue
On_IPurple='\033[0;105m'  # Purple
On_ICyan='\033[0;106m'    # Cyan
On_IWhite='\033[0;107m'   # White
```

Comment: Guess - you are running the script in the $PWD with `bash scriptname`, so `scriptDir="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"` results in the script name (there is no path info to trim from the right) so `[ -f ${scriptDir}/script.conf ]` fails -- explaining your `It seem like the script is stopped when INFO is 0.` This is not a guess - ANSI colors are nice -- but are generally more trouble than they are worth if you need any type of portability. (not t mention their impact on script readability if used heavily -- even with nice names for the escape sequences)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried without colors and it still didn't work. Also `script.conf` is correctly sourced. Otherwise even the first error message would not have been printed right?

Comment: If you look at your output `++ Color_Off='\033[0m'` is from sourcing `source $HOME/Templates/bash_colors.sh` in `script.conf`. Your next output is `+ INFO=0` meaning sourcing `${scriptDir}/script.conf` in `testConf.sh` failed.

Comment: Mh... I am not sure I understood this correctly. I execute `testConf.sh`. If the sourcing of `script.conf` would fail I wouldn't do anything related to colors. It would just set `INFO` to 0 and would try calling all the `__msg_*` which would fail. Even tracing wouldn't work as `set -o xtrace` is set in `script.conf`.

Comment: Okay, I agree with what you are saying there. Go ahead a post your `bash_colors.sh` so I can pull them all down and see what it going on.

Comment: Thx... I added the `bash_colors.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing what you have told it do. In `scipt.conf` you set a number of flags, particularly the `errexit` flag and initialize your error, debug and info flags:

```
INFO=${INFO:-"1"}
DEBUG=${DEBUG:-"0"}
ERROR=${ERROR:-"1"}
```

And you create your functions that make use of the flags:

```
__msg_error() {
    [[ "${ERROR}" == "1" ]] && echo -e "${Red}[ERROR]: $*${Color_Off}";
}

__msg_debug() {
    [[ "${DEBUG}" == "1" ]] && echo -e "${Yellow}[DEBUG]: $*${Color_Off}";
}

__msg_info() {
    [[ "${INFO}" == "1" ]] && echo -e "${Cyan}[INFO]: $*${Color_Off}";
}
```

(**note:** your `ERROR`and `INFO` flags are set to `1`)

Then in `testConf.sh` you set `INFO` to `zero` so the only messages that will be output is with `ERROR=1`

```
INFO="0"


__msg_error "Test error1"

__msg_info "Test Info"

__msg_error "Test error2"

__msg_debug "Test debug"
```

Running the scripts give the expected output, `"Test error1"` and `"Test error2"` are displayed fine and quite red, e.g.

```
$ bash ./testConf.sh
[ERROR]: Test error1
[ERROR]: Test error2
```

**Note:** however it is mandatory you provide `"./"` before the filename, otherwise the condition I discuss in the first comment will occur, (you concatenate two filenames since there would be no path information when run from $PWD without the `"./"` causing the test and source to fail.

When you complained only one output was shown, the `set -o errexit` causes the entire script to exit on the first error. If you want to follow what is done, just add `set -x` as the fist line under `#!/bin/bash` in your script. You will find the exit was triggered due to the comparison for `'Test Info'` failing `[[ 0 == \1 ]]` and it would be normal behavior to then exit skipping the `Test error2` output.

In `conf.script`, I would suggest a validating both the existence and non-empty nature of the file to be sourced before attempting the source, and also check that the source completed without error, e.g.

```
colorfile="$HOME/tmpd/bash_colors.sh"

if [ ! -s "$colorfile" ]; then
    printf "error: file not found or empty '%s'\n" "$colorfile" >&2
else
    . "$colorfile" || {
        printf "error: failed to source '%s'\n" "$colorfile" >&2
    }
fi
```

(**note:** you can use `'.'` to source the file into the current. `'.'` was the orgiinal source operator, but sometime later the alias for `source` was added as well.

Let me know if you are having problems elsewhere. It may be a stray character like a *carriage-return* stuck in your file that is not copied when I copy the snippets down.

Comment: Removing `set -o errexit` actually solves the issue. Now I see both error messages. Thx. 

However I wasn't aware that `[[ "${INFO}" == "1" ]]` is considered an error an bash exit.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Generally, unless you have read `man bash` with a fine-toothed-comb before setting all of the options, it is best to stick with `set -x` for initial debugging. Good luck with your scripting!

Answer (score -1):

If you set INFO to `0`, you have the following assignments to the variables which are relevant to `__msg_error`

INFO : 0

DEBUG : 0

ERROR : 1

Hence, only *ERROR* is printed.