# bash script colors not working when run from script

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm trying to add colors to a bash script I'm writing, and I'm following [this](https://dev.to/ifenna__/adding-colors-to-bash-scripts-48g4) tutorial.

Wehenver I copy/paste and run in my OSX terminal (OSX 11.3.1)

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

RED="\e[31m"
GREEN="\e[32m"
ENDCOLOR="\e[0m"

echo -e "${RED}This is some red text, ${ENDCOLOR}"
echo -e "${GREEN}And this is some green text${ENDCOLOR}"
```

I get the proper output, with the colored text. However, after saving this in a file, `colors.command` and run `chmod +x colors/command` and then try to run the script either by double clicking it, or `./colors.command` the output I get in my terminal is:

```
\e[31mThis is some red text, \e[0m
\e[32mAnd this is some green text\e[0m
```

How can I fix this so that my script outputs the colors properly when run?

Comment: As stated in [one of these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux#comment24883926_5947802), for MacOs, use `\033` instead off `\e`. So for red, use `RED="\033[31m"`

Comment: Replacing `\e` with `\033` solved my issue, thank you so much!

Comment: @LucasP. : I would not expect double-clicking a shellscript file to magically cause colours to appear, but I created a file with the exact content of your program, and when I run it, I can see the coloured output.

Comment: @user1934428 what OS are you using? On MacOS it only works after following 0stone0's suggestion

Comment: @LucasP. `cygwin` running on Windows 10 inside a mintty terminal, and `TERM` set to _xterm-256color_.