# bash: Capture and colorize parts of output before writing to stdout

Tags: bash, shell

I am capturing output from a command/script in a variable. The output is essentially a block of text. In the context of this question, let us consider this:

```sh
output='In java, both Errors and Exceptions are the subclasses of some/long/path/to/file.java class. Error refers to an illegal operation at line=23 and executed by app=client
```

**Problem:** I like to colorize parts of the message before writing to stdout. I managed to find a way but makes sense / works just for one substitution.

```sh
color_end=$'\33[0m'
color_red=$'\33[31m'

echo "${output//line=/${color_red}LINE=$color_end}"
```

I like to match and colorize other parts (say `<filename>.java`, `app=`) too. I tried using regex in the variable substitution above but none of these work. Getting syntax errors or the like.

```sh
echo "${output//(line=|app=)/${color_red}$1$color_end}"
```

Tried using `sed` but 1) colors are interpreted so when writing to stdout 2) gets a bit hairy with regex pattern.

What is the best way to achieve this?

---

FWIW, it is only one color for all the matched parts. Not different colors for different matched parts.

Comment: With pure bash, I can't think of any other way than doing the substitutions one by one. What doesn't work with sed? `sed -E "s/(app=|line=)/$color_red\1$color_end/g" <<< "$output"`

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux/69885917#69885917) cover what you're trying to do? BTW, parameter substitutions with `${var/pattern/replacement}` use glob patterns, not regular expressions, and don't support backreferences.

Comment: @Fravadona I did not include the `-E` flag and was getting bad substitution error. But with that, I think I am in a better shape if not absolutely done with what I am doing. Let me pursue with `-E` and see how it goes. Thanks a ton.

If you could post it as a reply, I would mark it as answer because it definitely according to me is a working solution.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Approach wise I should say in my mind it was along the lines of the post you have linked. I did not want to perform substitutions as separate commands (or pipe it). The sed with multiple `-e`s is a life-saver. Thanks for sharing the link.

If you could post it as a reply, I would mark it as answer because it definitely according to me is a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
# Only set colors if printing to a terminal
test -t 1 && t_red1=$'\033[31m' t_01=$'\033[0m'

# List here the regexes to highlight
echo "$output" |
sed -E 's/[[:alnum:]_]+=|[^[:space:]]+\.java'/"$t_red1&$t_01/g"
```

- This could be done in pure bash using `BASH_REMATCH`, but `sed` is simpler, and probably more efficient.
- The regex for the file path works here, but is brittle - a space in the path will break it.
- But you can use this template to add the regexes you want to highlight.
- `test -t 1` ensures the variables are only set if stdout (fd 1) is a terminal, which is important.
- `t_red1` refers to **t**erminal control sequence for color **red**, on file descriptor **1**.
- I use this notation because it's relatively short for embedding in strings, `t_` distinguishes from other variables, and the trailing fd number allows for separate control sequences per file descriptor (each of which may or may not be a terminal).
- For example, to use colored error messages (on fd2/stderr), you would add a line like `test -t 2 && t_red2=$'\033[31m' t_02=$'\033[0m'`.