# Is it possible to utilize a CLI (module/app/library) for use in my own Python script?

Tags: python, module, command-line-interface

I am fairly new to coding but love Python and am trying to understand something as I've run into a specific issue I need solved!

To give an example for context -

I am currently trying to stylize a pyfiglet title (centered) as a colored gradient. There seems to be no way to do this ASIDE FROM:

https://github.com/wasi-master/gradient_figlet

However, this is a CLI module/tool and I have no idea how to implement it into my script. There is no documentation and I am used to being provided with examples such as:

```
import gradient-figlet

gradient_figlet("TEST HELLO")
```

To give a printed gradient text (figlet) result as gradient-figlet accomplishes when used in command line using:

```
python -m gradient_figlet YOUR_TEXT
```

Is this possible in general?

Any help would be appreciated.

*On a side note - I'd really like to be able to center things in console if anyone has any tips :)*

Comment: _"On a side note - I'd really like to be able to center things in console if anyone has any tips :)"_ search for the relevant question, or [ask](/help/how-to-ask) your own if you don't find one that helps. Limit your posts to _one question_ please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with the creator of the repo and he kindly updated the repo to support usage within a script!

https://github.com/wasi-master/gradient_figlet

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I just found out this post, thanks lol.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like gradient_figlet has a non CLI implementation. However you could use subprocess to run the CLI and capture the output and use it.

import subprocess

the_result = subprocess.run(['python', '-m', 'gradient_figlet', 'YOUR_TEXT'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Let me know if this isn't what you are looking for!

Comment: Let me give it a shot!

I’m just wondering - won’t using this print the result in black and white? We shall see!

Let me know if you have any ideas on how to center it in console too!

Comment: import subprocess

the_result = subprocess.run(['python', '-m', 'gradient_figlet', 'YOUR_TEXT'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(the_result)

This does not work!

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cMD6DsW

Comment: Anyone know how to get it to properly print with color and formatting?

Comment: Sorry that didn't work how you expected. The stdout keyword makes it return bytes instead of strings.

try this instead:
subprocess.check_output('python -m gradient_figlet YOUR_TEXT', encoding='UTF-8')

I suspect that this will still be black and white.

Comment: Yes I was LITERALLY just about to let you know that was the case. It formatted the ASCII properly, but alas it's still black and white... any idea on how to retain color?

Comment: I have not a single clue.

I would start here, and combine it with catching the output of figlet

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux

Comment: Yeah, I've added a method to use the functions programmatically now so if someone wants to they can just call the function [`print_with_gradient_figlet`](https://github.com/wasi-master/gradient_figlet/blob/main/gradient_figlet/__init__.py#L69) in the script

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the library and I've since added a way to print gradient figlets programmatically. I initially wanted to add this in the initial release but it got delayed due to reasons.

You can use the [`print_with_gradient_figlet`](https://github.com/wasi-master/gradient_figlet/blob/main/gradient_figlet/__init__.py#L69) function to achieve this.

```py
import gradient_figlet

gradient_figlet.print_with_gradient_figlet("TEST HELLO", "#00ff00", "#ff0000")
```

The first parameter is the text and the next 2 ones are `from_color` and `to_color` There are a few optional parameters that you can check in the source.